# How do I correctly tag my questions?

Tags: support, faq, tags

Here are some tips for tagging questions. These guidelines will help you more accurately tag your questions, which in turn will help them get more attention and lead to better answers faster.

> For more information, see "[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### Effective Tags - Bring more attention to your question

- Each tag should stand on its own: if a tag only makes sense when used in a group with other tags, it's wrong.  For example, tagging a question as `[visual]` `[studio]` (two tags) is wrong.
- Pick tags that show higher counts in the look-ahead prompts, as they are more likely to make your question appear highlighted for a user on the main page or show up in someone's feed of watched tags.
- At a minimum, try to include at least one very broad tag (e.g., `java` or `c#`) and one other tag to narrow the topic down within that broader category (e.g., `strings` or `garbage-collection`).
- You are limited to five tags, and you are generally better off trying to use as many of them as you can, provided they follow the guidelines here.
- Try to use broad tags.  For example, you usually want to include both a general tag (`windows`) and a specific version tag (`windows-10`) rather than just the specific tag.  While tagging a question `cortana` on Super User might convey exactly the information you intend (it implies Windows, Windows 10, and Cortana all in one tag), tagging it `windows windows-10 cortana` will bring your question *lots* more attention, since more people will watch the generic `windows` and `windows-10` tags.  There is of course a trade-off: you used three tags to convey the same information you could have done with one.  However, it's hard to understate how many more views the generic tags will bring to your question.

#### Tagging Don'ts

- **Try not to create new tags.**  If you create a new tag, that tag is guaranteed not to help your question show up on any subscribed RSS feeds or watched tag lists.  Again, the look-ahead prompt can help with this.  Odds are it also means you're missing an existing tag for that topic that would more accurately categorize your question. See [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug)
- ***Don't* try to summarize your question using the tags.**  The point of tags on Stack Exchange is to help other interested users find your question by sorting it into clear, specific categories.  This is not the same as indexing or summarizing the question.  The differences are subtle, but important. Unlike many other formats like video, search engines can find your question using the text.
- ***Don't* use tags that are not *about* your question.** Again, the point of tags here is to help sort your question into clear, specific categories. Don't just slap a tag on your question just because it happens to mention a certain topic; only use tags that are *actually* about your question's topic. Tags that the question is not *about* don't belong.
- Don't use your username for a tag.
- **Don't use [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).**  Even if it already exists. A meta tag is any tag that doesn't categorize the content of the question, but simply indicates the nature of the question. Examples include `homework` or `hard-question`.
- Don't violate any site-specific policies regarding tag usage. For example, some tags may be slated for manual community removal from all questions per procedures defined by the site community, and Super User prohibits tags that are simply the name of a company and not a specific product.

#### Formatting

- Use all lower-case
- [Use American English spellings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/377214) (this is an exception to the normal policy that language in posts shouldn't be edited)
- Replaces spaces with dashes (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (i.e, Tag "`Unit Testing`" as "`unit-testing`").
- Avoid punctuation.  This can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL
- A number of tags predate the guidelines, and are therefore formatted differently. But that doesn't mean you shouldn't follow these rules when creating tags. If you find one of these, you should file a request on the per-site meta requesting that the tag be renamed to meet the guidelines.
- When naming a tag, think about how someone would search for that subject.  In most cases, this means typing out the full name, but you may also want to use the abbreviation in some cases.  For example, "`css`" is probably more appropriate than "`cascading-style-sheets`".

#### Retagging

Retagging a question is making any edit to a question that changes the tags.

- **Do not** retag a question if you are not going to add value to the question information by doing so.
- **Do** retag questions to use well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question.

Comment: "If you create a new tag, you are guaranteed to not show up ..." ... if that is the only tag you use.
Can we include some guidelines here about format of tags? For example, "sqlserver" or "sql-server"?

Comment: Fixed the wording there a little, Bobby Jack.  Is there a strong enough concensus yet on what the format should look like?

Comment: Formatting of new tags, right? For example, sqlserver has over 1100 questions, probably too many to re-tag them as sql-server if that were desired.

Comment: Well, the guidelines say "Combine multiple words into single-words". I understand that it makes sense to ignore this for certain names (e.g. "mysql" is correct, not "my-sql"!) but "SQL Server"'s name clearly includes a space.

Comment: @Dave: I don't think we should let a tag be if it's 'wrong', however much it's in use. If it's too big a manual job, it would be a less-than-a-minute job for one of the site owners.

Comment: You could argue that the presence of the Taxonomist badge encourages people to create new tags: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist

Comment: Sort of.  It encourages you to create new _good_ tags.  Personally, I think it should be a gold badge, but disqualify all the tags created during the private beta period.

Comment: @Bobby, good point - so maybe it should say (if you must create a new tag) "Combine multiple words into a single word, replacing spaces with dashes, such as sql-server for SQL Server."

Comment: Let's find a different example (one that doesn't point to a real tag that was done incorrectly).

Comment: How 'bout web-development or best-practices, as they're currently the first two dashed tags listed.  I was hoping for something shorter and more technical, though.

Comment: unit-testing? Other than that and file-io, everything else looks long.

Comment: I guess one of the reasons I raised the issue was that /something/ needs to be done to resolve the issue of hundreds of tags for "foo-bar" and 1 or 2 tags for "foobar". I've found this happening many times, and clean them up from time to time, but that's not too scalable. I'd like to see a ...

Comment: ... 'synonymous' relationship between relevant tags and/or corrections for badly formatted tags.

Comment: At some point too, we're going to have to tackle the tricky issue of what to do with, for example, a question specific to php 5.2.5 which will then need to be tagged with "php", "php-5", "php-5.2", and "php-5.2.5" - great, 1 free tag! Unless more implicit info. is stored somewhere, this will be a ..

Comment: ... problem (I've already seen similar examples; take a look at the number of posts with "sql", "server", "sqlserver", "sqlserver2008", ... etc.)

Comment: There's already a process that runs every hour on the backend to identify and correct known synonyms.

Comment: sql and server are both valid tags in their own right, so in that case it's more difficult.

Comment: One more note on why this post is important:  by the time the backend process runs (average of 1/2 hour later) most questions will have already dropped off the front page, and no one will ever see them.  If you tag them correctly upfront, then they'll get a lot more attention.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the info - how do you know all this? Would it be that inefficient to just run the synonym filter on initial submission? I guess my point about "sqlserver", etc. is that "sql" is redundant, but still useful, and a tag limit of 5 is very restrictive.

Comment: Actually, scrap that last comment about "sql": it's not totally redundant, since there could be sqlserver questions that are not strictly about sql. It's not as extreme an example as the php one, but it still holds for the "sqlserver" + "sqlserver2008" combo.

Comment: To follow up on that ... what about products with long names? SQL Server Management Studio, for example. given a sql-server tag, what else? ssms? sql-server-management-studio? management-studio?

Comment: Good point:  I think there's an ssms tag for that one, but that's pretty terse and hard to understand.

Comment: I think if I had it do over, I'd use 'management-studio'.  After all, Eneterprise Manager's full product name could also be "Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager" or "SQL Server Enterprise Manager", depending on whether you trust the title bar or the about box.

Comment: An actual lookup shows 9 Q's tagged 'management-studio' and 12 tagged 'ssms'.  There are also some other tags that have _no_ questions attached.  I'm gonna go retag the 12 ssms to use the guideline-following 'management-studio' version.

Comment: cool. I think it will be easier to find those as management-studio.

Comment: @Bobby Jack & why I know all this:  I've spent WAY too much time lurking here and at uservoice, so I hear things.  Also: using both the sqlserver _and_ the sqlserver2008 tags in the same question adds value, because someone may subscribe to a feed for one tag and not the other.

Comment: @Joel: thanks for the explanation. I understand the value-add, and this is my very point: having such a small number of tags per question AND having such a simple tag model discourages comprehensive classification.

Comment: Here's another tip suggestion: use the most frequently-used version (or the standardized version) of a tag. In other words, if you tag your question as "continuous-integration", don't also tag it as "continuousintegration", "continuous-integration-question", and "ci".

Comment: I think that falls under the 2nd bullet point.   Perhaps it could be worded more clearly?

Comment: With some questions, it seems like the 3rd point outweighs the 2nd; people will tag with two-words, two, and words so they can use five tags, particularly if "two" and "words" are standalone tags as well.

Comment: "Don't use your username for a tag." - Unless you're Jon Skeet.

Comment: Does the community User still re-tag?

Comment: Yes.  But I don't think it does as good a job keeping up with all the tag "synonyms" as it could.

Comment: Why does it say "use lower-case"? You're forced to do so!

Comment: Can we discuss "tangential-as-best" tags? See, eg, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397002), which is essentially a Jenkins CI to TeamCity setup question with a drive-by reference (turned tag) to JSLint. *Nothing* about using Crockford's tool here.  It's completely about an unnamed wrapper for JSLint that's used in some build processes. Is the drive-by legit? (The OP link & `you are generally better off trying to use all 5 of them` from this answer seem to encourage stocking up, but as a JSLint tag-sitter in this case, the linked question is spam to me.)

Answer (score 8):

### Is There a Standard for Tag Names?

- Please **do not** re-tag a question if you are not going to add valuable information by doing it.
- Please **do not** use tags as an attention-getting-device if you don't have sufficient privileges in the system (i.e., adding `[belongs-on-serverfault]`).
- Please [do not use the "duplicate" tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions) or any other tag that [does not contribute to categorizing the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question), including `[not-programming-related]`.  These kinds of tags are known as meta-tags; more information about them [can be found here.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- Multi-word tags should have the words separated by a dash, unless it is a proper name that does not have a space between the words. (I.e., `[sql-server]` and `[mysql]` are correct)
- Avoid creating new tags, if at all possible. Double-check your spelling if necessary. Some tags could have local variations (i.e., color or colour), some are predominantly singular or predominantly plural (i.e., color or colors), and some may have synonyms with completely different spellings (i.e., newbie or beginner). If a similar concept tag is already available, please **do not** create a new tag: use the existing tag instead. The goal is to categorize your question.