# Rename [internationalisation]

Tags: support, retag-request, meta

If the standard for tags is U.S. English rather than British English, then [internationalisation](/questions/tagged/internationalisation) should be renamed to [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization) (with a synonym left behind).

<del>Although, really, it should probably be merged to [localization](/questions/tagged/localization).</del>

Comment: Remove the tags and add localization where appropriate I'd say? There are only 34 of them.

Comment: According to wikipedia, [internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) have slightly different, complementary meanings. I know Wikipedia is not a source, but well. PS Is English flavor to use on SO defined anywhere?

Comment: ["For tags, US-English"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/161198) @Mołot.

Comment: @Bart Thank you, good to know. So I agree with spelling correction and synonym, but not with merge to [tag:localization]. Some computer-related companies uses these two terms as different processes so it would only be a matter of time someone came here to split them as his question is about one and not the other. Just my two copper pieces ;)

Comment: Yes, well, someone has already taken the initiative to retag "internationalisation" to "localization", even though we haven't yet reached a consensus.

Comment: That neither tag has a tag wiki doesn't help.

Comment: Or just rename it to `I18N` instead. Much easier to type.

Comment: And unfortunately the editor's username does not reflect the ease with which we can revert the situation @AlEverett... ;)