# Should data-modeling and data-modelling tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-modeling seems to be the winner with 971 questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-modelling has 65

Any reason they shouldn't be synonyms?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modelling - according to the dictionary, both are correct. So which is the synonym and which is the original tag?

Comment: @jmort253 modelling is the British English way of spelling it, so modeling it is.

Comment: lol @animuson. I guess if you were British we'd throw in the extra L? :)

Comment: @jmort253 According to Shog, [tags are supposed to use American English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873).

Comment: @animuson - Good to know!  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[data-modelling](/questions/tagged/data-modelling) (British English) has been merged and synonymized with [data-modeling](/questions/tagged/data-modeling) (American English).