# Tag Synonym: [greyscale] to [grayscale]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The tag [greyscale](/questions/tagged/greyscale) should be synonym to the tag [grayscale](/questions/tagged/grayscale).

Comment: Rather too many there to retag by hand.

Comment: What about using http://stackoverflow.com/tags/greyscale/synonyms to suggest one? I think this functionality of the site is not used very often.

Comment: I happen to prefer the British spelling of grey, but they mean the same thing, so I think a synonym is in order.  I doubt there are many who have the requisite score in the tag, so we'll need a mod to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer "grey" but we're supposed to use the American English form of words when it comes to tags, so [grayscale](/questions/tagged/grayscale) it is. Synonymized and merged.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a specific place where we say that American English takes precedence over British English?

Comment: @Dennis http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873

Comment: Ah, okay. Good to know.