# Can you debate a mod if they make an edit on your question?

Tags: discussion

A mod changed a few spellings on one of my questions that I don't agree with. Where is the best place to discuss this with him?

Comment: You can @-mention any editor under a post. So @nameofuser will notify them of your comment.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work. The @-mention just appeared as plain text

Comment: It always does, it doesn't get linked

Comment: Quick check: is your debate about the change to US English [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1389741/revisions)?

Comment: It is. Is that the standard?

Comment: Well, it is not my pet peeve but the consensus is that you shouldn't edit English that is correct. Some think otherwise so it depends on who you run into.

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us but it could be that a specific site decides to deviate from that advice. Check the local site meta.

Comment: Just change it back. No need to debate. The editor probably has spell check in only one language. In addition, he isn't a mod. I am ;p

Comment: What @JourneymanGeek is saying is that the user who changed colour to color on your question isn't a moderator. They're just a normal, high-reputation user. Mods are indicated with diamonds next to their usernames. We believe in collaboration here, so we let anyone edit nearly any post on the network, though in some cases they get reviewed before going live.

Comment: I'm assuming that this user is attempting to help by changing the spelling of colour to the most commonly used variant, to allow people to search for this issue.  SE's search for "color" and "colour" returns different results.  The editor missed one of the "colour" words (possibly intentionally), so a search for both would have found this question.