# What makes a good tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-block-request, ambiguous-tags

I just read the [tag FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878) and it didn't seem to make clear that tags should be unambiguously meaningful. I would suggest that a "good tag" be one that you could write a tag wiki excerpt for (and not just copy a definition out of a dicitionary).

This was prompted by clicking on the [level](/questions/tagged/level) tag and seeing that there is no useful definition of it. Same for:

[admin](/questions/tagged/admin)
[issues](/questions/tagged/issues)
 [item](/questions/tagged/item)
 [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) (duh!)
 [next](/questions/tagged/next) (would have been a great tag 20 years ago!)
 [separate](/questions/tagged/separate)
 [from](/questions/tagged/from) (seriously?)
 [repeated](/questions/tagged/repeated)
 [ideas](/questions/tagged/ideas)
 [arrow](/questions/tagged/arrow)
 [moving](/questions/tagged/moving)
 [deleting](/questions/tagged/deleting)
 [project](/questions/tagged/project) (who's not working on a project?)
 [line](/questions/tagged/line)
[change](/questions/tagged/change)
[part](/questions/tagged/part)
[riddles](/questions/tagged/riddles)

Am I wrong here? Are these good tags?

Answer (score 9):

If you can remove the tag without affecting the question then it's a bad tag as it's a meta tag.

So [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) would fall into that category.

Some tags like [item](/questions/tagged/item) or [project](/questions/tagged/project) are ambiguous at best. The latter could refer to the project in general terms, or Microsoft Project, or the project file and so on.

[moving](/questions/tagged/moving) and [deleting](/questions/tagged/deleting) are also ambiguous - what are you moving or deleting?

While there is a case for the wholesale deletion of meta tags from the database you would have to check each of the other questions individually to make sure that you replaced the suspect tag with something more meaningful. Perhaps there's a case for a silver and gold version of the "Organiser" badge for 80 and 500 tag edits (to match Strunk & White and Copy Editor).

Answer (score 1):

Tags are like keywords. Some users probably even don't know that there are any rules related to tags, and they simply type keywords related to their question. If they have enough reputation a new tag will be created. The only way to reduce this is explicitly ask for new tag creation or increase reputation needed for tag creation.

The problem with too many tags can be also related to [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge. If you want the badge you must create a tag. The amount of meaningful tags is limited so people will begin creating poor tags or duplicate tags.

If you have enough reputation you can simply modify a question if you see bad tagging. I think tags without any questions are deleted. Tools also offer listing of [questions with new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-tags). I think there is also some background process deleting rarely used tags.