# Should the [float] tag be banned?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

A quick look at [float](/questions/tagged/float) and [floats](/questions/tagged/floats) shows that there are two unrelated uses for the tags: floating-point numbers and a CSS style.

Is that useful to anybody? Should `float` and `floats` be banned from any future uses?

I would also suggest that any current uses be changed to [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point) or [css-floating](/questions/tagged/css-floating) but there are over 1,100 of them that have to be manually checked and edited.

Comment: We're getting a little overzealous on some tags here

Comment: Is there a [sink] tag?

Comment: @Rosinante: No, but searching for "sink" yields more results than "float"!

Answer (score 3):

`float` is an actual keyword in C# and Java (and a few other languages too).  It has a very specific meaning: a [32 bit single-precision floating point number.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)

I see your point about its ambiguity with CSS float.  But I don't think your proposed solution is better than the current situation, although I would be in favor of creating a tag synonym for [floats](/questions/tagged/floats).

Comment: `float` has a specific meaning in C#, a *different* specific meaning in Python, and an unrelated specific meaning in CSS. From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions: "•Each tag should stand on its own: if a tag only makes sense when used in a group with other tags, something is wrong." Since `float` only makes sense when combined with `css`, `html`, `python`, `c#`, `java`, etc., when is `float` ever right to use?

Comment: @Gabe: New users will never figure out your logic, and since there's no way to satisfactorily tag synonym the `float` tag, I'd say it's better to leave it the way it is.  Note that you can always qualify the tag with `css` or `python`; this is why we allow multiple tags on a question.

Comment: If you don't allow `float` as a tag, then when they type `float` into the tag box, they'll see `floating-point` and `css-floating`. At that point won't it be obvious which one to choose?