# A[n] [In]complete Character-Limiting Guide to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq-proposed, character-limit

The Stack Exchange network user interface has **a lot** of forms, and subsequently, inputs with various character limits in place. Some of them are notorious (such as custom moderator flag character limit or the custom suggested edit reject reason one), some are less well-known.

It is past time we had a **definitive** guide on those for the sake of having documentation and for providing a unified place for tracking changes to the limits (should such a thing occur in 6 to 8 time units), so the question is:

> What are the various character limits across the Stack Exchange network?

The scope of this Q&A is limited to character limits only.
For a detailed guide on **rate-limiting**, see the [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899).

Comment: I've attempted to make the reference as complete as possible from the start, but it is a work in progress - please do let me know what I missed or should be added (moderator tools limits, articles limits, etc)

Comment: *"It is past time we had a definitive guide"* - the reading should not be rushed on this one.

Comment: Anyway, kudos for the initiative.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Area 51

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes/Images |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example question | 15 | 150 | Min: [image: example question dialog - min] |
| Proposal topic | 3 | 150 | Min: [image: choose a topic field - min] |
| Proposal audience | 15 | 250 | Min: [image: describe audience field - min] |
| Proposal champions | 15 | 500 | Min: [image: describe organizers - min] |

### Bounties

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes/Images |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bounty remarks (total characters) | 30 | 3000 | Min: [image: expectations dialog] Max: [Reduce Character Limit for Bounty Custom Text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/reduce-character-limit-for-bounty-custom-text) |
| Bounty remarks (paragraphs/lines) | 1 | 4 | Max: [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text) |

### Close votes

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes/Images |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Other - add a comment" off-topic reason | 30 | 500 | Min: [image: off-topic reason dialog - min] |

### Close reasons (Mod-only edits)

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brief Description | 10 | 100 | e.g. "No longer reproducible" |
| Usage guidance, Close description, Post owner guidance, Privileged user guidance | 25 | 500 | See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgd5s.png) |

### Chat

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single-line message | 1 | 500 | Max: [What is the maximum length of a chat room message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119807/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-chat-room-message/297928#297928) |
| Chat search | 0 | 80 |  |
| Room description | 0 | 500 | Max: [Chat room info/description max length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260124/chat-room-info-description-max-length) |

### Contact Us

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Problem description | 15 | 5000 | Min: [image: contact us form - min] |
| Help center search | 0 | 300 |  |

### Edits

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Edit summary | depends | 300 | Minimum is 10 if suggesting an edit or you're a moderator editing an existing edit summary. There is no minimum for binding edits or when suggesting an edit to a tag wiki when you have enough reputation to review others' suggestions but not enough to make binding edits. [image: Please enter at least 10 characters] On Stack Overflow in Japanese, [the minimum is 5](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2001/14055) instead of 10. |
| Suggested edits | 6 | depends | There is no max length limit for registered users, other than the post length limit. For anonymous users, there's an undisclosed limit, and hitting it will ban the IP address for 7 days. Sources: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) |
| Redaction explanation | 1 | 300 | [image: Text field labelled "Redaction summary" with placeholder "explain what's being redacted (removed login information, expunged personally-identifying information)" and a red "Redact revision" button and a "Cancel" link] |

### Elections

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nomination |  | 1200 | Max: [Does anyone else think the moderator nominations are TLDR?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170496/does-anyone-else-think-the-moderator-nominations-are-tldr/170504#170504) |
| Questionnaire |  | 12000 | This is where candidates answer the questions. |

### Flags

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes/Images |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "In need of moderator intervention" flag reason | 10 | 500 | Min: [image: custom mod flag dialog - min] |
| "Something else" comment flag reason | 6 | 200 | Min: [image: custom comment flag dialog - min] Max: [For both post and comment flags, increase the maximum length permitted for the text of custom flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303444/make-the-moderator-flag-comment-max-length-longer) |
| Declined flag custom reason | 10* | 200 | Min: [image] |
| Helpful flag reason | 10* | 200 | Min: [image: helpful flag reason - min] |

* The minimum length is only checked client-side and is not enforced server-side.

### Help Center (Mod-only edits)

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blurb under the favicon, [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) | ??? | ??? |  |
| "Ask about.." and "Don't ask about...", [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) | ??? | ??? |  |
| [What topics can I ask about here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) | ??? | ??? |  |
| Area under the search bar, [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) | 0 | ??? |  |

### Posts

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Answers | 30 | 30,000<sup>2</sup> | Max: [Please increase the maximum allowed length for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers/14142#14142) |
| Community Wikis | 30<sup>1</sup> | 30,000<sup>2</sup> | Max: [Character limit for wiki answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123342/character-limit-for-wiki-answers/123347#123347) |
| Comments | 15<sup>1</sup> | 600 | Min: [Why was the minimum comment length of 15 chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228213/786798) |
| Question body | 30<sup>1</sup> | 30,000<sup>2</sup> | Min: [Do some Stack Exchange sites have longer minimum question lengths than others?](/q/108487/377214) Max: [Is there a limit on the length of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/is-there-a-limit-on-the-length-of-a-question/29162#29162) |
| Question title | 15<sup>1</sup> | 150 | Min: [Able to break the minimum title length restriction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160875/able-to-break-the-minimum-title-length-restriction) |

<sup>1</sup> On Stack Overflow in Japanese and its per-site meta, the minimum requirement for question bodies is 20 characters, and the minimum requirement for comment bodies and question titles [is 8 characters](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3085/14055). This applies regardless of community wiki status. *Answers* are subject to the network default of 30.

<sup>2</sup> On Code Review, the character limit is 65,536 for all posts; see [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/implementation-of-stddeque-obsolete#comment184668_101038). On Meta Stack Exchange, the limit is 50,000.

### Profile

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| About me | 0 | 3000 | Max: [Could we get "n characters left" status when editing "About Me" in our profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/could-we-get-n-characters-left-status-when-editing-about-me-in-our-profile) |
| Display Name | 3 | 30 | Min: [Prevent (or at least notify about) display names shorter than 3 chars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693) |
| Full Name | 0 | 100 |  |
| Location | 0 | 100 |  |
| Moderator annotatons | 10 | 300 |  |

### Reviews

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suggested edit rejection reason | 20 | 400 | Min: [image: custom rejection reason - min] Max: [Increase the character limit of the custom edit rejection reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350360/increase-the-character-limit-of-the-custom-edit-rejection-reasons/381995#381995) |

### Search & Filters

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Site search | 0 | 240 | Max: [Remove the max length restriction on the search boxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187508/remove-the-max-length-restriction-on-the-search-boxes) |
| Tag search | 0 | depends | Registered users may search for an unlimited number of tags. Anonymous users are restricted to searching for 3 tags at a time: the 4<sup>th</sup> and later tags are stripped out of the query; this applies even if wildcard tag syntax is being used, in which case it will be fully expanded to all matching tags and all except the first three will then be stripped out. |
| Tag filter | 0 | 35 |  |

### Tags

| Input Field | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tag names | 1 | 35 | Max: [Raising the 25 chars limit for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490) |
| Tag excerpts | 20 | 460 | Min: [image: tag excerpt field - min] Max: [The Tag Wiki dropdown should display the entire tag wiki excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85518/the-tag-wiki-dropdown-should-display-the-entire-tag-wiki-excerpt) mentions 450, but the `data-max-length` on the input is actually set to 460 |
| Tag wikis | 30 | unknown — at least [44,000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) | Min: [image: tag wiki body - min] When editing from the revision history page (e.g., to edit from an old revision): [30,000 characters](/q/329373/377214) |

Comment: This is a nice start. Next, I have to wonder about moderator-only fields, such as those for the help center. Or even Tag Warning text, which can only be set by a developer, I think. (I may see what I can add later.)

Comment: @Laurel yeah, mod-only fields would be nice to have too - I got so tired of running around trying to find the limits scattered in various posts that I finally decided to initiate the definitive guide :) Hope it takes off

Comment: The max length for election nominations is 1,200 characters

Comment: By the way, it isn't possible to edit this post with the new editor unless you're in markdown mode, otherwise the formatting gets all screwy.

Comment: @Laurel ugh, yes, do not even mention the new editor :)  I dread the time when it becomes mandatory (unless SE fixes the most egregious issues which, well, is far from guaranteed).