# Ambiguous word use in the "create posts" privilege help center page

Tags: bug, privileges, help-center

In [the help center page for question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), the first thing said is a quote from [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-question) (emphasis mine):

> Asking questions is a privilege, **not a right.**

However, in the [help center page for the "create posts" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts), the *first sentence* reads (emphasis mine):

> The most basic privilege of all -- **the right to ask a question**, and the right to contribute an answer. [...]

Answer (score 16):

Let's put aside how the question is worded, and think about this as a bug report.  Perhaps it would be better to use the alternative phrasing:

> The most basic privilege of all -- the **ability** to ask a question, and the **ability** to contribute an answer. This is generally available to everyone, regardless of reputation level.

I personally don't think it's wrong to say "right".  Virtually all rights are limited in some way.  Alice has the right to free speech, but if she uses it to loudly sing Cotton Eye Joe during courtroom proceedings...  Likewise, virtually everything at Stack Exchange [is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/351283) [limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372184/351283), e.g., I can't post more than 6 or 7 questions per day per site; I can't post answers with more than 30k characters.

But the OP has a point: it may be better to avoid using the word "right" because it's sometimes interpreted as implying it's "irrevocable".  And there does seem to be a genuine mismatch in using "privilege" and "right" (at least near-synonymously) in the same sentence.

Comment: Additionally, changing the sentence "This is generally available to everyone..." or adding more explicit explanation about privilege can be "lost" or restricted would make it more clear that there are rules to be followed.

Answer (score 6):

> Asking questions is a privilege, not a right.

One that can be taken away - that's what a question ban is.

> The most basic privilege of all -- the right to ask a question, and the right to contribute an answer.

If you've not *lost* the privileges to either, you have the *right* to post. Else you don't. That said, you have it by default so it takes effort to lose the privilege to have the right to post.

If you can't post, we don't really want people *demanding* the right to post they have lost due to, well, arguably their own actions.