# "Too many of your edits were rejected." while trying to add a tag wiki

Tags: support, tags, edits, tag-wiki, edit-ban

I am getting the message "Too many of your edits were rejected." while trying to add a tag wiki. Am I banned from such edits? Is the ban temporary or permanent?

Comment: I like the explanation give in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85187).

Comment: You do know you can see how your suggestions are doing on your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9522658/avin-mathew?tab=activity&sort=suggestions It is better to keep on eye on that tab and go over the current rejections to prevent mishaps going forward in 7 days.

Comment: Also helpful if you prefer focusing on editing tag wikis: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one

Comment: Specifically: stop copying content off external sites.  That's not acceptable _anywhere_ on Stack Exchange, especially where it's not cited.