# Is there a notion of "primary tags"?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-hierarchy

Are some tags more important than others? Is there something like a "primary tag" that identifies the largest-scope problem domain which always appears first?

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376085/undefined-function-or-method-for-input-arguments-of-type-double), the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag only appears second, even though the fact that this question pertains to Matlab is far more important than anything else.

Basically, every tag that identifies the programming language should be listed first. More generally, there could be a hierarchy of tags (a DAG, I suppose, if tags can have [multiple meanings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85100/should-each-tag-have-one-and-only-one-meaning)) determined by how quickly one is able to discard a question as not interesting, and tags should be presented in that order.

Is there any such feature already in SO? If not, would it be desirable?

Comment: Various forms of tag hierarchies have been proposed quite a lot: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/tag-hierarchy-absence-design-reasons, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/implicit-tagging-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it looks like the author simply typed "undefined function" into the tag box. The question isn't really about functions - it's about a specific error. In fact, the only useful tag on that question *is* [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) - so the solution is to strip out everything that's not relevant.

Comment: Interesting -- so if we remove overly broad tags that aren't quite pertinent, then the simple frequency-based ordering should be the right one?

Comment: That's the idea... Doesn't *always* work, but stands a pretty good chance.

Answer (score 5):

Tags appear in the order of how frequently they're used on the site.  For example, on the question you linked to the tags used are:

[image: Tag Frequency]

It normally works out that the language will be the first tag listed, since the language tags are used a lot, but in cases where the language isn't as widely used you can see this isn't always the case.