# Mark a tag as "no primary tag"

Tags: feature-request, tags

Some tags almost never make sense as primary tags. For example [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) or [string](/questions/tagged/string). If we cold mark those somehow as no primary tags (that would be something associated to the tag, no something that would be decided in each question asked), then we would never have the problem of those tags being primary instead of the obvious primary tag, like [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell).

In essence, tags marked as "no primary" would always appear after normal tags.

This is not a big problem in Stack Overflow, but in [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) the tag [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) is becoming a problem for all games, and we are [discussing posible solutions](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/818/2474). Some other tags overshadow game specific tags often, too. Perhaps other Stack Schange sites have similar problems.

Edit: I'm aware that this is not the first time that a fix for this problem has been requested. But this has an advantage over other similar requests (at least the ones that I have found in meta): the person who is asking the question doesn't need to do anything, so asking a question doesn't get more complicated. I don't know how this is implemented, but probably an algorithm that doesn't depend on the question for the order, only depends on the tags (like the one I'm suggesting), is easier to implement.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/is-there-a-notion-of-primary-tags

Answer (score 2):

I assume by primary tag you mean the tag that is put in the title. Some control over this has been requested on Gaming multiple times in different variations. All of these requests were shot down by SE.

The current "solution" to the problem on Gaming is that two tags are put in the title. This is a pretty hacky way of ensuring that the game name gets in the title even if there is a second, more popular tag on the question.

I haven't looked closer at your exact situation, but I'd recommend to just nuke the [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) tag, it doesn't sound like a tag that users would use to filter questions.. This is probably the easiest solution, at the moment tags that apply to questions about different games just plain don't work properly on SE. Gaming works around that by trying to use game-specific subtags. So instead of [wizard](/questions/tagged/wizard) we use [diablo-3-wizard](/questions/tagged/diablo-3-wizard).

Further information about this issue on Arqade (Gaming.SE):

- [Make a special tag class for "game tags".](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/make-a-special-tag-class-for-game-tags)
- [Allow tags to be blacklisted specifically from appearing in the HTML page title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title)
- [Why are questions adding the top two tags to the title?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/why-are-questions-adding-the-top-two-tags-to-the-title)
- [Sorting out the tagging mess](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess)
- [Why does Gaming.SE use tags differently from other SE sites?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/why-does-gaming-se-use-tags-differently-from-other-se-sites)
- [A personal appeal to Jeff Atwood: Recent Changes to Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/a-personal-appeal-to-jeff-atwood-recent-changes-to-gaming)

Comment: What I'm asking for is really similar to the link about blacklisting tags.