# Using the "wiki" tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I have a question about the meaning of the tag *wiki*.

Let's say I've worked really hard to build and compile a library on Windows, and I want to share with you on Stack Overflow on "how to do it easily" so other people won't have to "rediscover" my work.

So is all I have to do (in order to do it right) to add *wiki* to the tags I want to use?

For example: C++ build wiki zip.

(unfortunately ziplib does not exist although sharpziplib does exist, but I guess zip is enough for tagging).

Comment: No, if you're going to tag something `[wiki]`, it should be __about__ wikis. See this FAQ entry: [How do I correctly tag my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)

Comment: @Popular I think he is talking about tag wikis, not [wiki].  @strDisplayName do you mean the tag named [wiki] or the individual tag wikis that go along with each tag?

Comment: @Daniel and @Popular, I meant to add "wiki" as one of the tags I'm adding.
For example: C++ build wiki zip
(unfortunately ziplib does not exist although sharpziplib does exist, but I guess zip is enough for tagging).

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what tags you would like to add to your post. It might make things clearer. The "wiki" tag should only be used for posts about wikis as @Popular Demand pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to share some insight just keep to the question and answer format. Pose it as a question (in the example, how to build and compile a particular library on Windows) and answer it. It is customary to wait some time before posting the answer to let others have the chance to answer.

The tag *wiki* is for questions that are concerned with wikis, as in *[How to integrate a wiki with Mantis bug tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910201)*.

If by wiki you are referring to [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) state then it has been deprecated as a mechanism for "I-don't-deserve-any-rep-for-this".

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstood the concept of tags on SE sites.

- Tags are added to questions; you cannot create a tag without to associate it to a question.   In your specific case, it would mean that you ask a question about your own work, and add a tag that doesn't exist yet. You could do it if you have the necessary reputation to create new tags; otherwise, you can only use existing tags. The necessary reputation to create new tags is 1500, on *Stack Overflow*, and other sites.
- Tags on Stack Exchange sites are separated from a space; if you use "C++ build wiki zip" as tags, you are adding 4 tags. Of those tags, "wiki" doesn't have a particular meaning on *Stack Overflow*, if not when you are using it to refer to Wikipedia-like software; SE software doesn't treat it in any particular way.
- On SE sites, the tags are associated with questions, not answers. Supposing I have created a library called "rzkarch," which is a hypothetic library to create archives of compressed files, and I answer to a question saying that "rzkarch" is the library that suits the needs of the OP, I cannot tag the question with [rzkarch](/questions/tagged/rzkarch) simply for the fact I cited that library in my answer.
- On SE sites, there is a tag-wiki, which is a Wiki page that describes a tag, and its purpose.