# Should we burninate [id] tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

Looking at the Community Faq for [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions/18879#18879)

> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

I think [id](/questions/tagged/id) is meta-tag (as described by [Jeff in a blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) ) and should be burninated

---

[Note by MTibbits]: Personally I don't think this is a meta tag -- I added links and edited trying to keep the OP's intent -- **but I still think it should be removed**.  *I think [id](/questions/tagged/id) is ambiguous* and should be removed to avoid many-to-one tag synonym relationships: e.g. [global](/questions/tagged/global)+[unique](/questions/tagged/unique)+[id](/questions/tagged/id)=[guid](/questions/tagged/guid).  See my answer below.

Comment: **To your pitchforks!** Seriously, `[id]` can arguably be a legitimate standalone tag. After all, there's no `[html-id]` tag (yet).

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? :-( Think about all those **729** questions that will miss the tag.

Comment: @Siva most of them don't lose anything without this tag

Comment: @Siva, sorry but It's hard to me to differ serios thing from jokes in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 2):

When I began this answer, I thought it was reasonable to keep this tag.  There are times when [id](/questions/tagged/id) is *the* fundamental concept of a question.  For those other times, e.g. when a question would be tagged with:

- [session](/questions/tagged/session) [id](/questions/tagged/id)
- [user](/questions/tagged/user) [id](/questions/tagged/id)
- [orderby](/questions/tagged/orderby) [id](/questions/tagged/id)
- etc.

or even:

- [identity](/questions/tagged/identity)
- [identification](/questions/tagged/identification)

That these more specific contexts would be identified by the tag suggestion mechanism and the users would be more likely to realize: [session](/questions/tagged/session) + [id](/questions/tagged/id) = [sessionid](/questions/tagged/sessionid).

However, if you [search the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and type in 'user', the tag [userid](/questions/tagged/userid) appears so far down that *it wouldn't be suggested.*  I believe, at present, the dialog only shows six options.

I think this is a case of [many](/questions/tagged/many)+[tags](/questions/tagged/tags)+[mapping](/questions/tagged/mapping) = [many-tags-mapping](/questions/tagged/many-tags-mapping) to a more specific tag.  At present, the synonym system is not designed to support/handle many-to-one relationships.

Hence, **I now too think this tag should be deleted.**  Should a user wish to use [id](/questions/tagged/id) only, they still would have the option of [identity](/questions/tagged/identity) or [identification](/questions/tagged/identification) which are quite contextually similar.

Comment: You would have to first identify each variation of the tag and fix it, before you could remove the [id] tag.

Comment: Yep.  It's will be a lot of work - Something I certainly wouldn't do without unanimous/blessed approval.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that makes me vote for burnination is this:

> **Is the tag likely to be searched?**

That's my one rule for tag validity.

User case 1: I'm an expert at [some technology|concept], I want to look at [some technology|concept] questions.

User case 2: I have a question regarding [some technology|concept], was this question asked before?

In my mind, I see no reason why people would want to look-up [id](/questions/tagged/id) questions, nor any possibility of there being an [id](/questions/tagged/id) expert.

Burninate (or combine with session/user) it is.

Comment: No, but you might search for [session]+[id]

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then the tag should be [sessionid] or [session-id].

Comment: While there's been a recent push towards more specific tags, it's not at all self-evident to the average user that [sessionid] is better than [session] [id].  A search for [session]+[id] seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But it becomes a non-issue when tags that can be misleading are no longer available, especially to new users who don't have tag creation rights.

Comment: True, but if you typed in "session id" it would convert to "[session] id" and the appropriate questions would most likely still show up.

Comment: I keep tabs on certain tags with RSS feeds to prevent them from propagating. Among others, [tag:my], which is a valid Perl keyword, but is often used for MySQL, which users will enter as "my sql".

Answer (score 0):

No, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) suggests its used in combination with very specific things, like **[How can i get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)**, which uses `android image resources id` tags.

Comment: Isn't that just an indication that people don't know how to tag? For example, there are questions tagged [session] and [id] when there's a perfectly good [sessionid] tag available.

Comment: While there's been a recent push towards more specific tags, it's not at all self-evident to the average user that [sessionid] is better than [session] [id].  Also, [sessionid], by convention, should have a dash in it, i.e. [session-id].