# No more burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags, taxonomy

**Question:** When making these requests which lead to [visits from Trogdor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92746/burninate-the-easy-tag/92758#92758), am I to assume that these tags are blacklisted?  Or are they just removed?

In other words, would it make more sense to re-categorize these requests as:

- [tag-removal-request](/questions/tagged/tag-removal-request) which **doesn't** exist
- [tag-blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request) which **does** exist

[image: No moar burninashun?]

**Background:** I just noticed that someone blew away the [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag.  Oh well;  I don't mind the loss of the meme, but I *would really like the ability to categorize and search these requests*.  I was just asking Tim Stone about the [a](/questions/tagged/a) tag and wanted to find a related question here on MSO.  Can't seem to find it now.  That said, I was probably mistaken anyway.  ;O)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being specific enough?  Does `burninate == blacklist` or `burninate == removal`?  Because I assume that `removal != blacklist` <- tags which are *removed* **can** come back.  Tags which are blacklisted can't.

Comment: Tags aren't usually **blacklisted** until they've been destroyed once already, but keep coming back. Generally, removal is sufficient for all but the most persistent of tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) was burninated.

(irony?)

I think [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) should be sufficient.

Comment: But I *just* got around to actually watching Trogdor!

Comment: @John, just? Shame!

Comment: You destroyed Trogdor's home tag? Have you no soul, man?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) that has the following excerpt:

> A request for one tag to be replaced with another tag in the system. Also applies to requests that one tag should be merged into another.

The request for removing a tag could be a request for re-tagging the questions that use that tag to remove it.

[tag-blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request) is more specific, as it doesn't imply that a tag is removed by all the questions using it (and not just a subset of those questions) and it is not possible to use the tag anymore for any question. It is different from merging two tags and making one the synonym of the other, as when you request a tab to be blacklisted, there isn't a better tag to be used instead.

As for what *burninate* means, it could mean both removal or blacklisting; for example, there is a request to burninate [id](/questions/tagged/id), [Should we burninate [id] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101257/should-we-burninate-id-tag) but you are still able to add [id](/questions/tagged/id) to questions. The tag has been removed from questions, but it is not blacklisted; therefore, *burninate* doesn't necessarily means "blacklisting a tag."