# Burninate or cleanup: "header" tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

As far as I can tell, the [header](/questions/tagged/header) tag is used for at least 3 distinct things:

- HTTP & SMTP header fields (often with [php](/questions/tagged/php), [iis](/questions/tagged/iis), or [apache](/questions/tagged/apache)) — could be replaced with [header-fields](/questions/tagged/header-fields)
- Page/document headers (usually [css](/questions/tagged/css)-related) — no good replacement I can think of
- Header (`.h`) files (usually [c](/questions/tagged/c)- or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)-related) — could be replaced with [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files) (which, by the way, should be merged with [header-file](/questions/tagged/header-file))

Replacing these all with other tags would be hard, but I don't think it would cause any problems if [header](/questions/tagged/header) were just burninated entirely.

Comment: -1 for using a [burninated meme.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103197/no-more-burnination)

Comment: @john -1 for posting the same cranky comment over and over.

Comment: We need a [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)–type page for you, Jeff. ***"Only Jeff Atwood has the power to downvote comments."***

Answer (score 2):

The tag summaries for [header](/questions/tagged/header) and [footer](/questions/tagged/footer) are also inconsistent - the former refers to the header on a network packet, while the latter refers to the footer on the page of a website/document.

It's possible this isn't an issue, but do we really need [footer](/questions/tagged/footer)? To me, it seems like a fairly basic layout function rather than something that needs its own tag.

Quick list of the various uses of [header](/questions/tagged/header):

Simple content at the top of a page:

- [Positioning full width header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008393/positioning-full-width-header)
- [Ways to keep the same header on every page of the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015473/ways-to-keep-the-same-header-on-every-page-of-the-website)
- [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

C++ headers and how to include them:

- [Can I use an enum as a parameter without including the header that defines it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025010/can-i-use-an-enum-as-a-parameter-without-including-the-header-that-defines-it)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023770/invalid-initializer-when-trying-to-get-return-value-from-function
- [Getting a compile link error in the following program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012309/getting-a-compile-link-error-in-the-following-program)

And yes, there are a some questions about HTTP headers as the tag wiki suggests:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023770/invalid-initializer-when-trying-to-get-return-value-from-function
- [xmlhttprequest takes full header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014523/xmlhttprequest-takes-full-header)
- [Parsing out IP address and RDNS server from string in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008673/parsing-out-ip-address-and-rdns-server-from-string-in-perl)

Although many seem to deal with specifically with the 'headers already sent' error message in PHP:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)
- [Absolutely cannot figure out header issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008093/absolutely-cannot-figure-out-header-issue)
- [Image header issue facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001817/image-header-issue-facing)

Although these are all related in the sense of including something at the beginning of something else, I think [header](/questions/tagged/header) especially is acting as a meta-tag, despite its specific tag-wiki, made worse by the fact that so many of the issues are those that plague beginner programmers.

It would be a hell of a retag operation (there are currently over [5,000 questions tagged with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header?sort=newest)) - would any meaning be lost if the tag were simply burninated?