# Stack Overflow - Remove a localized tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tag-deletion

The tag [file-get-contents](/questions/tagged/file-get-contents) on Stack Overflow is dependent on the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/377968) states the tags should not exist if they cannot stand alone on a question (which this one cannot).

How can it be removed? Does it need a moderator attention? Or can a normal user vote on it for deletion?

Comment: Because I don't know PHP, I can't comment on whether PHP's file_get_contents() function is a topic which requires a tag, but wouldn't it solve the problem to rename it [tag:php-file-get-contents]?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this requires a tag in the first place.

Comment: No, get_file_contents() is a function in PHP, there's no point of having a tag named after it.

Comment: @Pekka my point exactly, I'm saying there's no point in this tag, so it should be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote for getting rid of the [file-get-contents](/questions/tagged/file-get-contents) tag altogether.

## Burninate!

Comment: Awesome, but how do you vote for it? (is there something like vote to close or vote to delete on posts? or do you need moderator intervention?)

Comment: @Truth nope, starting a support request on Meta as you did is the canonical way to go I think

Comment: @Pekka - Yes, and adding the appropriate tag also helps if it needs to be blacklisted: the [tag:tag-blacklist-request] tag is for for problem tags that need to be permanently banned.  On a related note, [tag:retag-request] if you want to merge one tag into another and/or create a synonym, but I don't think that there are tags to request burnination (which you've correctly identified that this tag deserves) or to request tag creation.

Comment: @Kevin good points. Unfortunately, philistine Jeff has burninated  `burninate-request` which was the perfect tag for these requests

Comment: @Pekka - After some research, that seems to be due to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97565) (I disagree with the burnination of most of those tags...), and Jeff justified it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103197/no-more-burnination/103201#103201), stating that [tag:retag-request] should be used instead, despite the tag wiki stating otherwise.