# Where is my taxonomist badge?

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

I'm kinda mad.

I created [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) on Apr 30 2012.  I remember creating and thinking "lol it would be funny if it caught on. Then I'll get taxonomist badge".  I tagged another question or two with the tag.  I'm 100% sure [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) didn't exist before!

[image]

Anyway JEFF THE CYBERCRIMINAL deleted [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) [on my original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130764/shouldnt-the-tumbleweed-badge-not-be-a-badge), on Aug 4/2012 of that same year

[image]

Now 105 questions use the tag!  But I am not recognized as the clever taxonomist that I am.  So angry.

Comment: You can always get it for [tag:cyber-crime] ^^

Comment: hmm According to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/101417#comment263387_101417) the tag did exist before but got burninated itself. Does the reintroduction of a burninated tag mean you deserve the taxonomy badge? I'm not sure one way or another.

Comment: I find [this revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/111236/4) on Nov 7, 2011 interesting. The comment is *Added wrongly burninated burninate-request tag.* but the tag that was added was `retag-request` This suggests that a tag merge was created which changes the post history.

Comment: Finally here's two more comments pre 4/2012 comments of interest [*note - I reallly wanted to create a burninate-request tag.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97565/trogdor-your-services-are-requested#comment245815_97565) and [*@Kevin good points. Unfortunately, philistine Jeff has burninated burninate-request which was the perfect tag for these requests*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111236/stack-overflow-remove-a-localized-tag/111240#comment288382_111240)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Taxonomist badge is only [awarded once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/167443). You've [already earned it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=111307) for creating [undelete](/questions/tagged/undelete).