# Create a new tag for a piece of software with limited user base?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I had the impulse to create the new tag [pgbouncer] for [Postgres - ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611926/postgres-error-prepared-statement-s-1-already-exists). It is tagged [Posgresql] which isn't wrong, but it is really about [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer). I felt the urge to tag it accordingly. However, this fine connection pooler does not have very many users or (luckily) problems to generate lots of questions on SO. A tag would not be used very often.

I have read up on the topic and am aware of the efforts to keep the number of tags at bay. I only recently gained the retag privilege and don't want to abuse it right away. How does the community feel about such a case? Should we create a new tag, or not?

#### Edit

Pretty much everybody seemed to be in favor of creating the new tag, so I went ahead and tried it. Missed that part:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> ```
> users with less than 1500 reputation can't create new tags. The
> ```
>
> tag 'pgbouncer' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.

Comment: Can you post some question links to what you read up on about the "efforts to keep the number of tags at bay"? I'd like to familiarize myself with those.

Comment: @RobHruska: Search for "[[faq]] tag" or "create new tag" here on meta and you get it all.

Comment: I get plenty of results with those searches, but nothing directly addressing "keeping the number of tags at bay."

Comment: Yeah, I just did a few minutes of searching with combinations of terms like [create, new, tag, too many] and got nothing significant. Most tag reduction efforts are directed at reducing *duplicate* or *unnecessary* tags. New tags for a real library or tool are fine.

Comment: @PopularDemand: There is a whole system of tag synonyms and merging tags. There is a limit of five tags per question. There are restrictions on who can create new tags. Here, the **faq** explicitly says "[Try not to create new tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)" .. if it does not "help your question show up on any subscribed RSS feeds". And last but not least, it's common sense. Tags are only useful if they reduce information. To what extent, is the question.

Comment: I would argue that most of those things are designed to keep the number of __bad__ tags "at bay,"and that that is materially different than merely keeping the total number of tags low.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Your interpretation makes sense. Still, the faq I quote has a different emphasis: it tells me not to create a tag, if I don't expect any subscribed RSS feeds on it. Makes sense, too, in a way. One has to draw a line where to start lumping things together.

Comment: The FAQ just says to *try* not to, not to explicitly not to. Not to create new tags for new things would be not too good.

Comment: Plus, the bit about RSS feeds and tag lists is just there to provide a reason why a new tag won't help you get views. But that doesn't mean adding it is wrong, especially if it makes sense.

Comment: @RobHruska: nobody suggested *not to create new tags for new things*. You are losing me there.

Comment: I'm basing that off your statement *"it tells me not to create a tag, if I don't expect any subscribed RSS feeds on it"*. But IMO that's an incorrect interpretation of the FAQ. It doesn't say *not to*, it says *"**Try** not to create tags, because doing so won't get your question noticed."*

Comment: @RobHruska: Yeah, I slightly misread that part. Anyway, I wanted to know how the community feels. So far, people seem to be in favor of creating the tag, and so am I.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a reason it shouldn't be created as a new tag simply because it has potentially low volume.

I say tag it.

<sup>If it's not a problem, it'll stick and you'll be on your way to earning a [[Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist)] badge. If adding the tag was the wrong thing to do, [@Charles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135887/charles) will come along and nuke it and you will have sullied your reputation with him. All fear the tag-nuking wrath of Charles.</sup>

Comment: When doing so, consider [reviewing questions that mention pgbouncer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pgbouncer) and tagging them as well.  A newly created tag that doesn't have *only* one question attached to it is much less likely to get nuked by new tag deletionists like myself.

Comment: Seems I (and everybody else) missed the part where I need to have 1500 reputation before I can create new tags. The "retag" privilege does not include that, apparently.

Comment: So I worked my way up to 1500 reputation and created the tag. We'll see if it sticks. Update: did a search for more questions, and tagged a few where obviously applicable. As expected, there were not many.