# My new tag was denied because it was used for "this question only"

Tags: discussion, tags

I added the tag [iphone-standalone-web-app](/questions/tagged/iphone-standalone-web-app) to my question, [Remove form assistant from keyboard in iPhone standalone web app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7904892/918414), and it was edited out with the reason:

> "No, we do not need a new tag for this question and this question only."

Don't all new tags start with only a single question using it? I'm not sure how to create one otherwise.

Standalone web apps are a distinct category of iPhone web apps. They have their own settings, properties, and layout issues and even run on an entirely [different Javascript engine](http://www.reghardware.com/2011/03/15/apple_ios_throttles_web_apps_on_home_screen/). Tag aside, the difference is **essential to my question**, as it distinguishes it from other similar questions which are asking about web apps running in Mobile Safari.

I've read the [Create New Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) page and the FAQ, [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/172756), and I think I met all the requirements for a new tag. The tag is about a distinct category and it can be used on its own.

The searches, [[ios] +"stand alone" "web app"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+%2B%22stand+alone%22+%22web+app%22&submit=search), [[ios] +standalone "web app"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D%20%2bstandalone%20%22web%20app%22&submit=search), [[iphone] standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D%20standalone) and [[iphone] "stand alone"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D%20%22stand%20alone%22), return more than four hundred results, most of which are specifically about standalone web apps, and for many the distinction actually matters to the problem. Google returns some [18 million results](https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone%20stand%20alone%20web%20app) for "iphone stand alone web app".

Is this tag appropriate? If not, what requirements did I miss in the FAQ?

Comment: I guess you could retag existing questions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I wasn't sure if it was an appropriate tag. I didn't want to retag a bunch of stuff before Meta weighed in.

Comment: The New Tag Deletionist Cabal officially endorses Andrew's comment as the best way to keep us and our finicky edits out of your hair.

Comment: @Charles Hah! OK, got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Tag aside, the difference is essential to my question, as it distinguishes it from other similar questions which are asking about web apps running in Mobile Safari.

All 69 of them that are tagged as [iphone-web-app](/questions/tagged/iphone-web-app)? I don't think that primary tag has grown to a point where it needs to be split further. Besides, your title does state "standalone web app" so I'm sure they can figure it out. I agree with the removal.

Comment: Then what further requirements should be considered when deciding on creating a new tag? Volume? There are 4,500 [tag:ios] ones, many of which could be retagged.

Comment: This is actually a better iOS search, returning 78: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+%2Bstandalone+%22web+app%22&submit=search

Comment: Like Andrew suggests above. If you really think it should exist, go find as many as you can. Using your `[ios] standalone web app` search, I'm seeing a lot of `web` and `app` highlighted in the results, and not so much `standalone` highlighted. The ones which *do* get highlighted for `standalone` appear at the top, because they're more *relevant*. Oh, the power of searching! Searching for more detailed result using [`[ios] +standalone web app`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ios]+%2Bstandalone+web+app&submit=search) returns only 78 results. -- I see you found that one already.

Comment: I don't have any strong feelings about this particular tag. I more wanted to get a feel for what the requirements were for creating a new one. It *seems* to meet all the requirements to me, but since it was closed, I wasn't sure. You mentioned volume, and splitting out an existing small tag. This wasn't mentioned in the FAQ, so that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think if there was not a *better* tag encompassing the same meaning it would be allowed.

"Standalone web app" is not all that technical a term.  Kind of what you would search for if you didn't actually know the technical term for apps of this type.  Another version of this is [out-of-browser](/questions/tagged/out-of-browser) which already exists (I just updated the wiki), and the technical version, [ria](/questions/tagged/ria) (Rich Internet Application).

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: Eh.  "Technical term" might be... too technical?  How about "What stuff like this stuff is normally called by people who are talking about this stuff."