# Adding a new tag: how to judge if it's too localised?

Tags: discussion, tags

I edited an [old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7924818/471093), and added [cubature](/questions/tagged/cubature). The question is about numerical integration in multi-dimensional space, for which cubature is a [recognised mathematical term](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cubature.html).

Today I find the tag deleted, possibly because `cubature` is also the name of a specific package I used in the example. I wonder, what's wrong with adding a tag to SO that corresponds to a technical term with general use?

Comment: Related (comments mostly): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120555/my-new-tag-was-denied-because-it-was-used-for-this-question-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted it because it was only on that one question. Typically if you want to justify a new tag, verify that other questions are on the same topic to see how localized it is. If you see a usage pattern that seems justifiable, ***add the tag to those other questions*** in addition to yours.

There are currently five questions that mention *cubature*. Three of them are recent, but it's certainly a low-use concept for a tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cubature+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I see the topic of tag [specificity vs use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100067/187113) has already been discussed, and personally I don't think there's a clear-cut answer (a specific concept tag can be useful, however small the number of subscribers or tagged questions).

Comment: @baptiste If you think it's justified, by all means, create it. Just retag the others, too.

Comment: I was mostly curious to know the reason, after this discussion I'm now more convinced that the tag wouldn't help anyone here so I'll leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are for searching and filtering. Can you imagine 100 questions on that tag coming anytime soon? If not, don't make it. Think how many people will want to follow questions tagged [cubature](/questions/tagged/cubature). It seems a rather obscure package, so I doubt many people will need the tag. So it is too localised.

Comment: let me reiterate: the tag was for the technical sense of "numerical integration of a multiple integral". I believe it could well be used by other SO users if it was here to pick, precisely because it is a useful filter term, but of course I have no statistics to show for it. I worry the tag was deleted for the wrong reason (confusion with the package name).

Comment: @baptiste: Isn't [tag:integral] enough?

Comment: not nearly specific enough to be very useful as a filter, if you ask me. Mind you, I just noticed that even the more common `quadrature` isn't present, so I guess tags are not being used so much as specific filters.

Comment: @baptiste: So you expect folks to favorite [tag:cubature] but not [tag:integral]? Is there a separate community for this? Is it a radically different field?

Comment: `integral` is just really vague in my opinion, just one step from `mathematics`; I agree it's a blurry line though, and in this particular instance, considering the general low use of all relevant terms I can think of, `numerical-integration` was probably the best candidate.

Comment: @baptiste [tag:numerical-integration] would be exactly what I'd expect a) to find on such questions, b) people to search for.