# When should I add a tag onto a question?

Tags: discussion, tags, help-center

I most likely will be downvoted for this question, but I am confused on this matter.

If a question (for example, not in real life) about Harry Potter that mentions Ronald Weasley and has relations to him but does not go into detail about the character specifically, should I add the tag `ronald-weasely`? The help center page for [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) did not mention anything on this subject.

**So my current question is:**

**In what specific scenarios should I add a tag and when should I not?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) If this FAQ post doesn't answer your question, then please be specific about what you're unsure about.

Comment: Would the tag [tag:coriolanus-snow] be a new tag (to create), or would it be an existing tag? I see it doesn't exist on [literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags) or  [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: @SamOnela Strange. I thought it existed. I will change the example.