# Using comedic styles or Jokes in Answers

Tags: discussion, rules

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61101) on [Is the Stack Overflow source code available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14656)

Quite often, many StackExchange sites do have the occasional comedic style to a well written answers and comments. I have no problems with jokes.

But could someone explain the clearly defined limits of using humor, in upvoted answers?

If so, should the best answer be judged on the basis of quality and formality, rather than popularity?

Comment: It's old, from the days when Stack Overflow was small site. Things changed dramatically since then, so such answers won't be acceptable anymore. So guess [meta-tag:status-irrelevant] fits here. :)

Comment: I also think because Meta is sometimes more relax for this kind of case.

Comment: wait. I'm not allowed to add the status-irrelevant tag, since I don't have >500 reputation points. why?

Comment: @edition I was half kidding. :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Meta, everyone is a little relaxed on making jokes (there is even a tag for [fun](/questions/tagged/fun)). There was even a contest for the [big UPS outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself) (the title itself is a joke).

The [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag excerpt does say:

> Questions that are light-hearted but hopefully of **some additional use beyond mere entertainment**.

So it has to have some value.

On regular sites, it is best to check the help center on what is allowed, and for example this post: [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers).

As ShadowWizard commented, don't try to be too funny on MSE. After all, what you post has to be on-topic.

Comment: Even here on MSE joke answers on serious questions won't be accepted these days. Fun questions are also rare and hard to come with something that will fit. The "UPS outage" contest was led by a Community Manager, not ordinary user. (thus, rules do not apply)