# Is it just me, or is the "subjective" warning a bit over-active?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, subjective-warning

Lately, I seem to be running into the subjective warning a lot:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

I'm not saying this to complain.  I'm just curious if it's just how I'm phrasing my questions or if it's not just me that feels this way.  In particular, the warning comes up a lot when I start a question with "How do you..."

I don't feel this to be a good indicator of whether or not a question is subjective.  But this is just my opinion.  Have I been obliviously been writing horribly subjective-sounding questions and not knowing it?

Comment: I agree, there is a huge amount of subjectivity in programming simply because there are many approaches to each problem, and thus there is some subjectivity based on one's experience in terms of how you choose the approach that best fits.  If our questions must be completely fully deterministic and non-subjective, then we lose the opportunity to learn from the experiences of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that 'How do you...' is a trigger, where something similar like 'How does one...' is not.  If you want to get out of the rut of writing horribly subjective-sounding questions, there is some advice to be found [in this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles) which shouldnt trigger that warning.

Answer (score 2):

Ask questions for yourself, not of the world in general, and make good and sure that the title reflects that.

**Good:** How do I compile multiple C++ files in parallel?

**Bad:** How do you do your builds in parallel?

Comment: Better: How to compile multiple C++ files in parallel? / How to do parallel builds?

Comment: ...except for the fact that those questions aren't complete sentences.  :-)