# What is jeopardy compliance?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list

Somebody edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/826777/revisions) post of mine with the revision remark of "Jeopardy compliance". I tried to find what this is, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on [Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!): phrase it in the form of a question.

Answer (score 6):

[Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!) is a TV game show in the US.  Contestants are given an answer, and [they must respond with a question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!#Gameplay) - in other words all their responses have to be in the form of a question.

On StackOverflow, all questions have to be in the form of a question.  If there's no question mark, or English sentence that that is [interrogative](http://academicwriting.suite101.com/article.cfm/how_to_identify_the_four_types_of_sentences), then the "question" isn't a question.

The edit, among other things, made sure there was a question that people could answer.

Comment: I only see "the requirement" for Jeopardy in the part about answering one's own question, hence assuming it's just about separating the question and the answer. To me, the FAQ does not indicate that titles should be questions. (See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/question-titles-should-be-questions)