# Re: my recent demise and subsequent ascension to CloseHammer™ heaven

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

It seems the number of close votes has increased:

[image: Indicator saying 23 close votes remaining]

Where's the documentation for this little bundle of joy?

Comment: hahaha documentation. That's hilarious. *Documentation.*

Comment: he likely meant FAQ item...although the use of the word documentation is freaking hilarious...

Comment: Plz send teh documentation it is urgent.

Comment: Oh my god, this is incredible! I honestly think that this is the best feature to have been added to the site in a very *long* time. Now if only they'd start increasing based on some kind of quality or reliability metric...

Comment: Documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions, its still on 12.

Comment: Good find, @Gamecat. And it's 12 [on SU](http://superuser.com/privileges/close-questions) and [on SF](http://serverfault.com/privileges/close-questions) too, which actually has [always been 24](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/should-available-close-votes-be-a-function-of-inflation-or-rep/87291#87291) there.

Comment: 50 close votes at SO, take a look at [recent feature post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: @YOU: thanks. I actually checks that post before I edited, but I just didn't see that answer edit. Note to self: don't try to run on 3 hours of sleep

Comment: Voting to close all questions on Meta as a duplicate of the comment posted by @JeffAtwood, above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Arjan said below, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/should-available-close-votes-be-a-function-of-inflation-or-rep/87291#87291) is the closest we're going to get for the documentation, currently.

As per Jeff:

> The default # of close votes per day
>   is 12.
>
> I just noticed that SU and SF have
>   been at 24 close votes per day per
>   user since ... well, forever.
>
> I'm going to go ahead and make 24
>   close votes per day the new default
>   network-wide to start, and meanwhile
>   it has been set to 50 for SO.

Answer (score 7):

It is listed on the first answer to this question that has all the recent changes:

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: ...though I didn't add it there until I saw the above screenshot and started investigating ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, ah.  I did not pay attention to the the timestamps.  That is just the first place I look when I notice a change.