# Why do I have extra close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re: my recent demise and subsequent ascension to CloseHammer™ heaven](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87435/re-my-recent-demise-and-subsequent-ascension-to-closehammer-heaven)

According to [the close question FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) and [the voting limits FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits), users (> 3k rep) are only supposed to have 12 close votes per day. This is in line with what I've seen whenever I've cast close votes.

However, I just cast a close vote and was told that I had 24 votes remaining (23 now...). Is this a glitch where I was somehow given a two-day allotment of votes, or has the limit been increased?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think the allotment has been increased to 24 votes on all sites. Super User users have had 24 votes for quite a while now.

Comment: @RegDwight: Thanks. I didn't see that (due to the terribly descriptive title on that question... jeez). I voted to close this question rather than delete it since I think the title here is a bit more descriptive for people trying to find the information.