# Change the Ask Question page's field labels to "Question" and "Detail"

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

> Inspired by: [Better titles for questions?  Some tips on grammatical editing to make the site look better.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/better-titles-for-questions-some-tips-on-grammatical-editing-to-make-the-site-l)
>
> His followup: [Would the Stack Exchange network be better if titles contained complete, grammatical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/would-the-se-network-be-better-if-titles-contained-complete-grammatical-question)

#### The What:

**Can we change the *label* of the first text field on the Ask Question page from "Title" to "Question" and start referring to the second text field as "Detail"?**

I don't mind if we continue to not have the detail box labelled detail, but can we at least *call* it the "detail box" in questions, comments and discussions?

To use this post as an example, what you're reading right now is the detail, and "Change the Ask Question page's field labels to 'Question' and 'Detail'" is the question.

#### The Payoff:

We want people to ask good questions in the title/question field.

Here's the impetus for this request *(two randomly chosen questions to indicate a sort of "what's being asked here")*:

- [Do Nikon AF-S lenses perform better than AF lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/nikon-af-vs-af-s-lenses)
- [Divisibility rules and congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52778/divisibility-rules-and-congruences)

And some prior art discussion on Meta:

- [Encourage users to use question Title as a Title/Topic rather than an abbreviated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74498/encourage-users-to-use-question-title-as-a-title-topic-rather-than-an-abbreviated/74499#74499)
- [Should question titles be phrased as questions? (A straw poll)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll)
- [How can we get more people to make their title a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21606/how-can-we-get-more-people-to-make-their-title-a-question)
- [What's in a Title (line)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/whats-in-a-title-line)

Comment: I disagree that "summary" is (currently/should be) accurate.  We don't want the summary.  We want the details.  Even though there isn't a label, it is currently referred to as the "body" of the question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82064/is-it-possible-to-rename-the-title-field-to-question-on-the-ask-question-fo

Comment: I don't really understand this, or why you're proposing it. The title field seems correctly labeled to me: it is the *title* of your question. And as Rebecca commented, we don't want a summary of the question, we want the *actual* question, including all of the details. (Edit: I see you've just changed the suggested term to "Detail", but I don't think that's quite right either. We do want the body of questions to be self-contained. It should be the summary *and* the details. Do you really see this as confusing the way it is? It seems quite natural to me...)

Comment: I was expecting this to be about renaming the `Title` field to `Summary`, which seemed like a reasonable idea. It better describes what the title *should* be and maybe it would nudge a few people in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not that great at making compelling FRs on a regular basis. The gist of it goes like this: People post craptacular question titles. We want to make those better.

Answer (score 6):

So you want to name the body of a post as "summary"? To me, "summary" implies something that is "summed up" or simplified.  The part where we add in more detail is the exact opposite of a summary.

Comment: Fair and valid point. So we should call it "detail"?

Comment: How about "exposition" ;)

Comment: I like that, I don't think that everyone would get it tho ;)

Comment: Had to look up what "exposition" meant.