# Is "made title a question" a valid reason for submitting an edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I'm kind of curious; if I see a question with a title like this:

> How to x y and z

Is making the title a question a valid reason for editing it?

Comment: in general when the title sucks, the question sucks as well ... both need editing love

Comment: If I type "ma" into the edit summary textfield, the first and third autocomplete suggestions are "made title a question" and "make title reflect question" respectively. I've used these a fair bit...

Comment: I generally approve such edits, provided they describe the content of the question as well or better than the original. Simply tacking on a question mark is of course something to dismiss. But yes, questions should begin with a question, and (most) feel that the front page looks a bit better for it.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe I just can't easily find the original.

Comment: [Related but not exactly a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21606/how-can-we-get-more-people-to-make-their-title-a-question)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll

Answer (score 26, accepted):

People disagree drastically on what constitutes a "good enough" edit. Personally I say yes; we've had a user on the [Unix and Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) that's been doing just that, and I'm a big fan:

[image: Screenshot of the suggested edit stats]

The first thing the [CHAOS team](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/welcome-chaos/) did when they started was go through the top 1000 questions on a bunch of sites and [clean up their titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character/100359#100359), specifically turning them into questions if they weren't, so clearly it's considered important

Comment: Well, if CHAOS did it... (not saying I'm an equal or anything,  just that it must be acceptable behaviour).

Comment: @Mahnax Well, the argument you're going to get isn't "are questions in titles good", it's going to be "is it important enough to waste somebody's time reviewing the suggested edit". I say yes, but other people say no

Comment: Fair enough, I can see where they could be coming from.

Comment: Looks like they just did it to \*puts.sunglasses.on\* spread CHAOS. *YEEEAAAHHHHH*

Comment: TBH, I was wondering myself if some of my edits weren't a little small. I took your approvals to be a green flag.  :)

Answer (score 11):

That depends. If the only thing your edit does is to make the title a question, don't bother. This gets debated now and then all over Stack Exchange; I'm firmly in the camp that holds that titles do not need and often should not be questions, because

- the title is a title for the whole page, not for the question;
- having fully grammatical titles is not always desirable (think newspaper headlines): concision is paramount, so that the important words stand out — and question words are often noise;
- titles in the form of questions are less attractive in search results (I'm looking for answers, not questions).

[image: Wisdom of the Ancients]

On the other hand, if you're **improving** the title, and happen to make it a question, that's good. The key point is to improve; whether you turn a question into a non-question or a non-question into a question is irrelevant.

For example, the [title edits that Michael Mrozek shows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111011/is-made-title-a-question-a-valid-reason-for-submitting-an-edit/111012#111012) weren't just making titles into questions for the sake of it (the edit changelog message is misleading); they were generally (at least the ones I looked at) improving the title. For example, changing [“an echo question” into “What does the syntax of these echo commands mean?”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/23441/revisions) is a definite improvement. So is turning [“Linux Serial port problem” into "How can I monitor serial port traffic?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/12359/revisions). On the other hand, I have a slight preference for “Monitoring serial port traffic” — not enough to bother to edit, but it's the title I'd pick if I was editing the post for another reason.

Some final notes, if you intend to go into an edit spree. Thank you, but…

- If you're doing this on a site other than Stack Overflow, please pace yourself. Check the front page, and try to make your edits not be too big a proportion of it.
- Don't just edit the title; look for other things that can be improved (poor titles often go together with poor grammar and poor formatting).

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Taking an already perfectly good title (e.g., "Embedding a button in a UIPickerView", "Dealing with interrupted audio file download", "Creating class diagram for iPhone app") and adding "How to" and a question mark is a waste of edit reviewer's time (not to mention, adds noise to the title).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Therein lies the problem; how do we define, and who defines, what should and should not be edited?

Comment: @Mahnax: Does the title _accurately_ and _concisely_ describe the problem such that a reader will have a clear idea (especially combined with the tags) what they are about to see when they click the link? If yes, there's no need to make the title a question.

Comment: Please, *please* resist the urge to think about newspaper headlines while writing titles. We have *enough* problems.

Comment: @Josh: I've been reluctant to change question titles because I figured that regardless of how inaccurate or unspecific a title might be, someone asked it in that form, and therefore it may be useful for specific people in that form.

Answer (score 6):

If the title isn't actually a question, making it into one is a grammar improvement, and that on its own is a reason for editing it. But as waffles mentioned, it's a good indication that there might be other problems in the body of the question. So if I can, I try to improve the body as well, not *just* the title.

Comment: Making a newspaper headline into a complete sentence isn't a **grammatical** improvement, and neither is making a perfectly descriptive SO title into a question.

Comment: @Josh SO titles aren't newspaper headlines. I don't get your comparison.

Comment: They serve exactly the same purpose, to summarize the contents of the page they head and allow readers to quickly determine their expected level of interest. Question words in many cases are superfluous.

Comment: OK, and if you're summarizing the contents of a **question**, doesn't it make sense that the summary would also be a question? Seems to be a logical progression of content to summary.

Comment: Not necessarily, because either: you're searching on Stack Overflow, know what the site's all about, and expect to find a question, or you're searching the web and are looking for the answer to _your_ problem and don't give two hoots about whether it's in a question & answer format, a blog post, a tweet, or a webcomic, as long as you get the info you're after. The title needs to get people to read the page, and a question-form title is not intrinsic to that goal. Were every title in the database to start with "How to", it would only make it _harder_ to search.

Comment: If you start a sentence with "How to", it's not going to end up being a question-- it will only be a sentence fragment. This is, I realize, a moot point if you don't think titles need to be sentences. Moreover, we could just modify the site's search/indexing algorithms to reduce the importance of the words "how to" (and also remove those words from the meta keywords if necessary).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is acceptable. As a basis for my answer, I provide you with [Shog9's answer to a related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21606/how-can-we-get-more-people-to-make-their-title-a-question):

> That's why editing is so crucial: read the whole question, distill its essence into a single sentence, and replace the title with that question. At worst, you've managed to improve one question; at best, you've shown them how they should ask future questions

Since he is now a Valued Associated I consider that a pretty definitive stamp of approval.

Comment: Oh, cool, can we now take everything Shog9 has said in the past as official policy?

Comment: @mmyers Sure, why not? ;-)