# Arduino programming questions OK on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I just had two Arduino questions migrated from SO to Electronics.

It surprised me, as these are both pretty pure software questions related to using the Arduino library, meeting at least 3 of the 4 bullet points in the FAQ.

Am I mistaken on this?  Should I avoid SO for Arduino based coding questions?

[Arduino: better microsecond resolution than micros()?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22584/arduino-better-microsecond-resolution-than-micros)

[Arduino: faster alternatives to digitalread() and digitalwrite()?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22585/arduino-faster-alternatives-to-digitalread-and-digitalwrite)

Comment: For one thing, *please* don't put tags in your titles!

Comment: See [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/titles-should-the-most-relevant-tag-be-included-in-the-title)

Comment: Sorry John, but "better microsecond resolution than micros()" just doesn't convey enough data.  I've provided the canonical answer for this using assembler on Linux; I only need the answer for Arduino.  Besides, look at the link you gave, and note the author of the referenced question in the comments. ;-)

Comment: If people don't know what you're talking about, they can always look at the *actual* tags, right?

Comment: Please leave this open for comments regarding Arduino.  Go comment on titles and tags in my question from July 2009:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-good-titles

Comment: @MarkHarrison: Yes, please leave tags out of your title *unless they are "organic"*.  For example, "WPF: How do I datagrid?" is inorganic, pointless, and highly annoying.  "How do I datagrid in WPF?" is better, but the WPF part is well covered by the question tags.  The tag system on SE has been refined over a long period of time, and works great.  Sticking random tags in the title is pretty much useless.

Comment: @Won't: lol, look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-good-titles/10648#10648 . pay special attention to item 4, and the heatmap preceding.  Then note Jeff's comment in the answer following where he notes that google prefers the exact format this question uses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was the moderator who migrated these questions. The reason I did was because I thought that the [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site would service your questions better than on Stack Overflow.

In the EE.SE FAQ it states:

> We ask and answer questions about electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with **microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems**.

There's a buzzing community of Arduino enthusiasts on that site and I also noticed that you already got three answers quite quickly.

As a Netduino tinkerer myself I'd probably ask questions on that site first before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That makes sense Kev... thanks for the assist!

Comment: @MarkHarrison - no problem, and in the future, if you are in any way unhappy with a migrate, then don't hesitate to let us know.