# Disallow (at least top) tags to start question title

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them)

Seems that more than a half of my edits are about to remove c# from `c# <title>` and `c# - <title>`.

Lookup all the tags can be expensive, misleading and non-representative, but top x of well-known tags must be banned to start a title. Don't you agree?

Comment: The tag list is pretty static - it can't be *that* expensive right?

Comment: @awoodland: Out of curiosity, I decided to count. [Tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=888&tab=popular) indicates about 31968 of tags. Not expensive and not cheap. But after ~30th page tags below 1000 are present.

Comment: I'm sure this has been suggested before...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66152/titles-should-the-most-relevant-tag-be-included-in-the-title