# Can we extend the automatic removal of tags in question titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, title

As far as I can tell, only questions that have [tags in brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles) in their titles are automatically corrected with the tag removed. I don't know whether I've grown more sensitive to this lately, or whether it's an actual problem, but I've seen a lot of questions where the title begins with a tag, then a hyphen, colon, plus, etc. prior to the actual title.

For example;

- Magento - set gift message to existing order using php
- JQuery UI + ContextMenu: Send multiple selected elements from table to Dialog UI
- PHP: Loop returns error, but it shouldn't

It would seem trivial to extend the existing filter to clean up these other tag-tainted question titles.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84802/warn-users-before-posting-if-they-have-a-tag-at-the-start-of-their-title ; I'm not much in favor of more automagic corrections.

Comment: It's related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them/105245#105245 as well but there seems to be more support for it than against it.

Comment: I know, this has been debated more than once. Don't get me wrong, I don't like tags at the start of titles. It's just that autofix thingies are hard to get right.

Comment: Indeed, there are a lot of clbuttic mistakes you can easily make.

Answer (score 4):

Prediction: if you add a filter like this, you'll end up with

- Magento set gift message to existing order using php
- JQuery UI + ContextMenu Send multiple selected elements from table to Dialog UI
- PHP Loop returns error, but it shouldn't

This is an incentive towards worse titles. The cure is worse than the disease.

In any case, **filters should be viewed with extreme caution.** I've encountered false positives for all the title filters on SO that I'm aware of, e.g.

- Objective-C questions with a title like “[foo bar] behaves thusly but I want this instead”
  (Not a common problem, so I can live with this filter.)
- questions about, say, NP-complete problems having to be written as “NP-complete pro-blem”
  (This filter does no good because people just write “issue” instead, *except* for the legitimate uses which become unsearchable.)