# Tag: <- prevent this

Tags: feature-request, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them)

Tags don't need to appear in the title, there are some scenarios where this is ok, but certainly not in the format "Tag:title"

This should be prevented with help of a simple regexp and display a box with some guidance.

I belive 99%+ of the ones affected with this would indeed trying to put a tag, I doubt there is any legit use of "word:title" in a proper title.

**Note:** I am *not* saying to ban the use of ":", the regexp should only match single words, if there is a space in between it should ignore it.

Comment: @random sorry for my dupe (I was on mobile), but your dup link is also a dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84802/warn-users-before-posting-if-they-have-a-tag-at-the-start-of-their-title?rq=1