# On the ethicality of user-run April Fools' pranks

Tags: discussion, humor, gaming-the-system, april-fools

While I'm aware of today's [brilliant SO prank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-april-fools-joke-to-appear), I decided to *also* run my own*, because I'm in the uncomfortable position of topping SO's weekly user board today. I decided to use it to promote [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), which seems like the most appropriate place to send people interested in the memephilic sensation, [*My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Little_Pony:_Friendship_Is_Magic)

While I'm dodging tomatoes and hoping our fine SO admins don't take it as cause to kick me off the site, I wonder what you all think of user-managed pranks on April Fool's, as long as they're in perfectly good fun and *help* users find answers and communities they might not have expected otherwise.

Meta seems entirely appropriate for this discussion, because I'd been thinking of other ways to abuse my (brief) time in the spotlight to maximize entertainment for all involved without stepping on too many toes. So, other than my drawing the combined ire of everyone on Movies.SE, do you all think this kind of behavior is (a) manageable, (b) appropriate, and (c) in the spirit of this fine community here on SO?

(PS: Bronies.)

---

* Said prank has now been taken down at the conclusion of April 1<sup>st</sup>. I'd modified my profile to a picture of Big Macintosh and one additional pony from *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic,* replacing my profile text with:

*I've discovered my inner brony. Join me and all my friends at [http://mylittlepony.stackexchange.com](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)!*

Comment: *\* Brohoof \**

Comment: @TwilightSparkle This, literally, just made my evening.

Comment: Wait, what is the prank you're running?

Comment: @TheEstablishment A quick avatar-swap, and from the profile linkthrough: _I've discovered my inner brony. Join me and all my friends at [http://mylittlepony.stackexchange.com](http://movies.stackexchange.com)!_

Comment: Ah, yeah. That's totally cool. I don't even see that as a "prank". You're allowed to change your avatar and profile to whatever you want. I did it on Meta a while ago, and it's still amusing the heck out of me every time I cast a close or delete vote.

Comment: @MrGomez I also was thrilled, seeing this post so shortly after changing my profile. =D Just FYI there are [a handful of MLP:FIM questions on SF&F.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/friendship-is-magic).

Comment: I'm not a brony, but it disappoints me that there isn't a Stack Exchange site dedicated to My Little Pony. You all deserve better.

Comment: @TheEstablishment It's the sort of subtle humor that pleases me. The only thing bringing me to ask is, with the good fortune from last week, #1 status appears to confer about 100-200 profile clickthroughs a day. So, it suddenly becomes less trivial than it would be normally! :)

Comment: OMG Ponies... I approve of this posting.

Comment: Please rephrase your question in the form of gems

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As long as you aren't doing something that you would get a slap on the wrists for any other day, such as:

- Creating useless noise in the form of a question
- Creating useless noise in the form of an answer
- Creating useless noise in the form of a comment
- Putting pr0n in your profile / gravatar

**... On Stack Overflow**, I'm sure that everyone will take it as harmless fun and maybe laugh a little. Laughing is good.

Concerning pranks, when in doubt - don't.

Last April 1 I cleared over 600 flags in an eight hour period. That wasn't fun. I'm glad to see that the noise on the main site has been kept to a minimum this year, well so far - anyway.

I'd also hope that we keep shenanigans down to a dull roar on Meta as well, but my *personal* opinion is to be a bit more tolerant of April 1 fun here than on the main site. That's not the official stance, because as you know, [we tolerate only small amounts of constructive fun with steely, businesslike frowns](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Just keep in mind that it's our job as moderators to sweep up all of the confetti when the party is done.

**Update**

As far as 2012 goes, thanks for not making a mess, and thanks for making me laugh :)

Comment: It being a Sunday you stand a far greater chance of less people showing up overall. They are lazy.

Comment: @jcolebrand I know, what a lousy day for April 1!

Comment: @TimPost it's terrible, isn;t it?! Who decides these things.

Comment: **Every** action **must be** done in the **appropriate** place. Down

Comment: @BenBrocka. But ... but the 1st of April is a Saturday. Always. Appendix D says so.

Comment: "Putting pr0n in your profile / gravatar" - Did anyone actually try to do that?

Comment: @DVK Yes, well, pretty close. It was some kind of self portrait, and no, I don't want to talk about it.

Comment: @TimPost - Didn't notice any NY congressmen on politics.SE so far :)))

Answer (score 5):

Why not? Alright, new users may be confused, but that's no biggie.. On SO, anyways as a non-dev you can't do much for a prank. You can ask some prank-y questions, though these will probably be deleted(see comments).

As a precedent, take Wikipedia. [Pranks galore!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:April_fools/April_Fools%27_Day_2012).

I see four types of pranks:

- Most of the pranks there focus on doing meta stuff like [nominating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Snow) [stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Irony) [for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Logic) [deletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:MFD#Wikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion.2FWikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion.2FWikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion.2FWikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion.2FWikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion.2FWikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion_.283rd_nomination.29); and also  nominating [cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Requests_for_adminship/Ten_Pound_Hammer%27s_cat), [policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Requests_for_adminship/WP:NOTNOW),  and iPods for adminship.
- Quite a few of them focus on users: Reporting/blocking oneself for sockpuppetry, [marking userpages as historical](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:CycloneGU&diff=484943382&oldid=443188235), and [pretending](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Ron_Ritzman&oldid=484943781) to [leave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:TenPoundHammer) Wikipedia.
- A bunch of them focus on content. As I understand it, it's still a bit controversial to fiddle with content, even on April Fools' day. That's why the content-fiddling isn't listed on that page, but [here's an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hydrogen&oldid=484943339).
- And finally, extremely few pranks are there which require a bit of privileges to execute, but affect all the viewers. For example: [an admin changes the Wikipedia tagline to refer to a WP staff member](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Tagline&diff=484927099&oldid=411557037).. And of course there's the DYK on the main page.

Translated to SO:

- Pranks of the first type won't be really effective on SO, since we have a much lest robust meta-ness. Yes, we have MSO, but on MSO it's April Fools' day every day anyway. Nothing different we can do here. Can we?
- The second type is exactly what you've done. These are OK, but may not get much attention. Unless we have a meta-thread listing them.
- The third type would amount to either (a) editing old, popular posts and making them funnier. Not really funny. (b) Asking kooky questions. Of course, with SO's level of traffic, these may get drowned out. Or deleted(see comments).
- The fourth type would be quite hard to do. We already have Clip-cloppy, but I don't think the devs will do anything else that will affect the entire viewerbase. Or will they? Pretty please?

Comment: Clip-cloppy affects the entire viewerbase.

Comment: *You can ask some prank-y questions, though*. Please, no. Why possibly confuse users who're simply trying to help folks solve their problems?

Comment: What @Arjan said. [Seriously, don't try it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962286/plz-send-teh-codez) (deleted - visible to 10k users only, but just look at the permalink and you'll know what I mean)

Comment: @Arjan: Alright, fixed.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Whoops, I meant to add an _else_ there.

Comment: Well heck. I don't think there's anything *wrong* with asking a joke question or two one day out of the year. The challenge is to *do it well*. The question @Bolt linked is just a terrible question. It isn't even close to being funny. I guess it's supposed to be a complicated meta-satire on the generally poor quality of questions that we get on SO, but even as someone who loves subtle humor and critical theory, I don't appreciate it. Compare that, though, to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/). See the difference?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Ooh, now that's a good 'un :) I might try to do something of the sort on Physics.SE if I get time later on. (Over there its quiet enough that such stuff won't affect much--unlike SO)

Comment: @Arjan: [Just for today, and it's not confusing as it is an obvious prank but still a good read for those who want to read it. Others can just click away: "How does one get rid of fishy behavior in Windows?"](http://superuser.com/questions/407198/how-does-one-get-rid-of-fishy-behavior-in-windows) I do this annually, could have prepared some more. Previous year was [risks of using a computer case as a BBQ](http://www.cybersalt.org/images/funnypictures/c/computerbbq.jpg)...

Comment: I think, on rare occasions, [a well done prank question can be constructive](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly). They can force one to think outside the box. The rotating form-covered box.

Comment: @BenBrocka We really need a meta-thread to deposit all these :D

Comment: @Tom : decided to try it out on Physics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23130/7433

Comment: [For low views, this one is particularly controversial.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965146/creating-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Manishearth: Yes... I agree.

Comment: Here is a pranky question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/203458 that worked wonderfully and got some in-spirit answers. It's historically locked now, of course. The most upvoted answer did actually involve making you think about your assumptions and was interesting.

Comment: @KateGregory Yeah,, I remember that one :)