# Why was this question related to Spooning closed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I had a question related to the Spooning feature introduced by bitbucket.org.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967525/what-is-spooning

The question seems to be deleted. Can someone help understand what was wrong?

P.S: Please don't misinterpret spooning.

Comment: I think the "concept" of Spooning was an April Fool's joke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitbucket's "spooning" feature was an [April Fool's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) joke—i.e., it wasn't really implemented and wasn't meant to be taken seriously by anyone.

So either you missed the joke completely (in which case the question was probably closed and deleted as being noise or pointless), or you were playing along with the joke yourself in the spirit of April Fool's Day (in which case the question was probably closed and deleted either because your joke wasn't funny, because it was likely to be misinterpreted, and/or because April Fool's Day is over in most timezones and [someone has to clean up the mess that remains after the party](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127727/153008)).

Comment: To be fair, [the whole spoon thing can be quite confusing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJOdpwL6X6A#t=35s).

Comment: Damn...I never fell for an April fool's joke in my entire life.....and i fell for this.