# Please keep the Aprils 1st Unicorn for "parse HTML using Regex" questions

Tags: feature-request, clippycorn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep the functionality of clippycorn (while removing the annoyance)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127737/keep-the-functionality-of-clippycorn-while-removing-the-annoyance)

I came upon this ["parse HTML with Regex" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9970112/626273).

The user saw this (his comment):

> Umm...just a bit of sidebar topic here: as I was typing this post (most of the way through), a weird unicorn graphic showed up on the right side of the page and, like MS Clippy, asked me if I wanted help parsing XML, and then sent me here: stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/… When I came back to my post to take a screenshot of the unicorn, it was gone. Somebody please tell me that wasn't a hallucination. Somebody? Anybody? Hello?

I love this magic creature, knowing what the user wanted to do, bringing him to that [weird answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/626273) to show him the way.

That user didn't understood, but **please keep this nice, beautiful, helping, magic unicorn!**

Comment: Wow. That prank was so extensive that I feel like I probably missed 99% of it during the one day we had to enjoy it.