# "This title is too short to be useful"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, title

I was about to ask a question entitled "Speeding up R for and while loops", and noticed while hesitating that "Speeding up R" is apparently "too short to be useful".

So I thought I'd try "Speeding up PHP" - it's just another language and contains no more information than "Speeding up R" - in spite of this, the notice promptly goes away.

With this, is a minimum length check perhaps a bit... weak?

Comment: Perhaps your titles are a bit... weak?

Comment: @Oded - did you even read the explanation?

Comment: Well, it is clear from your description that the check for a title being too short is based on (ta da!) the length of the string.

Comment: @Oded - that is correct, congratulations. But it still does not address that you didn't read the description.

Comment: What? You added two characters and expect that the length of the title will be the same?

Comment: Well BoltClock added the bit that made me sound surprised about this.

Comment: Apologies, just wasn't sure what the question was trying to say.

Comment: Whatifwecountedthenumberofwhitespacecharactersinstead?

Comment: BoltClock - that is an acceptable question.

Comment: Since writing a [good question title is hard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/148672) its no surprise that coming up with good heuristics to ensure that it is one is also hard. But 15 characters does indeed stop lots of truly bad ones

Answer (score 14):

I think the check is doing a great job, actually.

"*Speeding up R*" is not really a useful title.  It's pretty vague; you should mention in your question title what, specifically, you're trying to fix.  "*Speeding up nested for loops in R*" **<sup>1</sup>** would be an improvement.

If you don't know enough about the problem to know which part of your code is slow, then perhaps you need to look a little deeper before posting **<sup>2</sup>**

Of course, "*Speeding up PHP*" is no better, but **there is only so much you can do with programmatic checks like this.  There has to be a limit somewhere.**

<sup>1</sup> I don't know anything about R, it might not even use for loops, but I think you get my meaning =)
<sup>2</sup> Please take that as a general statement, not a personal attack on you or your question.

Comment: I agree, there has to be a limit.  But I would have thought a better programmatic check would be to have a minimum word limit rather than a minimum length limit.

Comment: @dplanet - A better check would be for both # of words and total length.

Comment: I agree with @Oded.  Also, possibly removing tags from the title before doing the length check would be useful.

Comment: +1 for footnotes. I love footnotes.

Comment: @Shep I will take a +1 however I can get it =P

Answer (score 0):

"PHP" has two more characters than "R". So the minimum length for a title must be > 13 and <= 15 characters. Experimentation will show that it is, in fact, 15.

Whether this is weak or not is a subjective question. Seems fine to me.