# What if I can't answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, new-users, post-ban

Recently, I was banned for asking new questions on Stack Overflow. I can understand that my questions were probably wrong and I would have been search Google before I ask (even though I did it all the time).

But there's something that makes me think: [here the FAQ writes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) that "If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again."

I can also understand that "Stack Exchange web sites are question and answer sites", but what if I can't help to the others? I'm not a moron, I would **NEVER** ask the same question again, but my knowledge about programming and my English knowledge are not enough to help anyone properly.

I don't tell it to provoke anyone or something, but in my opinion, somtimes there should be counted on that there might be some absolute beginners.

Or maybe this site was not made for them?

Comment: There are undoubtedly beginner questions that even you might be able to answer. But there is another piece of the equation. Go try to salvage your existing questions, if possible. No guarantee if would help, but it certainly can't hurt.

Comment: Pro tip: _Don't_ start your titles with a tag. All your titles follow a "<tag(s)>: <title>" format, and that's a sign of forum-itis. The actual tags are more than sufficient for tagging your question, your titles should be as close to a natural sentence as possible.

Comment: On SO, I felt it necessary to explain with the first letter (C usually) already the "topic" of my question. Thanks for this!

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt More on titles: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking questions is fine, and asking beginners questions is fine - but it really is expected that people will read and follow the [faq] and [about] pages.

If you do this, generally you will be fine.

There is a difference between beginner on SO (or any other SE site) and someone who just doesn't follow the instructions given to all new visitors.

The good thing is, as you progress through your career, you will find that there will be more and more questions you can answer.

Comment: Well, you are totally right! I have the mistake that because I've always tried to act harmfully on the Internet, I've alwys ignored Rules/FAQs sections too, because I thought that I won't break/ask any of them.

Comment: " I've always tried to act harmfully on the Internet" - maybe this is a mistranslation or misunderstanding of the word, but this seems like an odd thing to say. If you're always acting harmful,  do we want you answering questions?

Comment: Oh yes, it was a fatal mistake, sorry! I meant, "I've always tried NOT to act harmfully on the Internet".