# Is the quality of question titles suffering due to over zealous reject point hunters?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I've recently improved the title of a question which suffered obvious capitalization issues and improved the grammar in the process:

[File read in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839048/file-read-in-angularjs) -> [How to read a file in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839048/file-read-in-angularjs)

The [review of suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2940311) shows that it was, in chronological order:

- rejected by a user with 2,472 rep
- approved by a user with 12,488 rep
- approved by a user with 6,349 rep
- rejected by a user with 2,107 rep
- rejected by a user with 4,291 rep

FWIW, all 'rejectors' ranked lower than the 'approvers'. Reasons for the rejections were all cited as:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive
>   improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

Though I missed formatting one possible character within the question body (an out of code formatted closing `}`), the rest of the question appeared fine.

It irks me to see incorrect capitalization of proper nouns throughout SO and title improvements should result in improved indexing for questions, reducing the amount of duplicates being asked.

Is this a case of me wanting my couple of points bad enough to complain or those doing the rejecting wanting their points more?

Comment: Seems to me if you think your title is really better and worth having edited in order to improve the post, you shouldn't have stopped at the title. There were things in the post itself which could have used help, too. Again; applying the standard you appear to have applied when making the title edit in the first place. In that regard, I agree that your edit was "too minor".

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I don't disagree with that and mentioned my single character ommission in my question. I would like to edit that and re-edit the title again now, but would that one extra character be enough to convince the nay-sayers to approve this time after rejecting the almost as substantive first edit?

Comment: One extra character? I see a number of other things that could improve the body of the question. Things that are arguably more important than what you did to the title. Truth be told, I don't think *any* of those edits were necessary... but there are numerous grammar issues in the post itself that I'm surprised you didn't jump on, considering your apparent nitpickiness with the title.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, fair point. I've revised my edit and re-submitted with improvements to the question body. As you say, none of them really major, but IMO, such titles should really be improved so I did a more thorough job.

Comment: I decided what I was posting here really deserved to be posted as an answer, so... voila!

Comment: You've just shown exactly why rep isn't a good metric for quality of a reviewer.  The people with the most rep made the wrong call, and based on their review history, this isn't just a one off.

Comment: Great point @Servy, I will rightly start to set my expectations the same for all reviewers.

Comment: One other comment: I think one could argue that adding "How to" to the title is a step backwards (as it does not really add much information).

Comment: @D.W., good point. [Jon Skeet's article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) I believe agrees with you when he states that it's preferred to be able to infer the meaning of the question when skimming, though if possible, all questions should be able to be formed as actual questions

Comment: @LeonStafford, if you want more reading, [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/160917) makes the case for that advice.  Not mandatory reading, just fyi in case you are interested in this stuff.  Thank you for your attention and desire to want to do the right thing, and for your constructive attitude in seeking feedback!

Comment: Thanks @D.W., that post does explain it well and one can see a distinct pattern of not requiring a "What/How/Why..." prefix especially if the leading word is a verb. I should put on my UX developer's cap and remove my "this is SO, so don't treat it like a website" one ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems to me that if you think your title is really better and worth having edited in order to improve the post, you shouldn't have stopped at the title. There were things in the post itself which could have used help, too. Again; applying the standard you appear to have applied when making the title edit in the first place. In that regard, I agree that your edit was "too minor".

For instance, in the post there is this:

> Hey guys is it possible to read files in AngularJS?

"Hey guys" could (should) be removed. But even if not removed, it surely should be separated from the rest of that sentence in some way.

> I want to place the file into an html canvas to crop.

HTML should be capitalized.

> I was thinking of using a directive?

This is not a question, and should not end in a question mark.

> }

You noted the stray `}` already, above.

> Thanks!

Should just be nuked.

---

Note that none of these things are horrible - but neither was the old title. As I said above, my feeling here is that if you felt the title should have been edited, those other things certainly should also have been done.

When doing edits that touch things which are really so minor, you should expect people to tend toward rejection. I can certainly see how the edit you did just plain might not look like an improvement at all.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you have set me straight regarding this case and I'll be more diligent going forward!

Comment: @LeonStafford You are very welcome! And truth be told, I like proper grammar myself! (Even if I don't always achieve it myself!)