# Overview about the post format standards on SO

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, markdown

For me it is important to see clear and well formatted question / answers on all of the SO-Network sites.
On meta, I found a lot of tips, how to improve Q&A. But is there any overview about some standards?
Or is it okay when I edit a Q or A for my own feel?

For example, I like it more when we use the given link format. So instead of http://www.google.com I like a link like [Google](http://www.google.com) <- that more.
Or when something code specific is written in the text like:
"Lorem ipsum HTML a tag Lorem ipsum" like that -> "Lorem ipsum HTML `a`-tag Lorem ipsum"

A lot of my edits are such minor edits like the examples above or also delete "Thanks" & phrases like this one.

For me it is important to edit such little changes to make a question more readable. But a lot of these Edit's are rejected, because the edit is **too minor**.

---

So is it okay when I edit a Q/A for my own feel?
Isn't it better when a question gets better formatted (also when the changes are really minor)?
Or is there a standard how to format a Q/A correct?

Comment: "HTML" isn't code, so don't edit it to make it look like code.

Comment: @Wooble: Yes, but sometimes it looks better with the code format. But in general, I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @dTDesign: you should _never_ format stuff that's not code with code formatting. That's why it's called code formatting: it's for code.

Comment: @Mat: So for example the second "code"-block in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1 shouldn't be a code block? For my feel, it looks better in a code block than with anything else...

Comment: @dTDesign Second block there should be, and as far as I see is, a quote. And quote block makes perfect sense.

Comment: Okay, yes me fault :S. Okay I understand the reason because the code block. Thanks! @Wooble +1

Comment: Well... I don't really have a big problem with using "code" formatting for error messages and tracebacks. Using it for random words was my objection.

Comment: @Downvoter: Reason?

Comment: You know how voting works on meta? Probably someone disagrees with something you seem to advocate in your post.

Comment: @Mołot: Sure, so he/she should tell me that. How I can know where i'm wrong...?

Comment: This is a big problem - if he would, you could randomly downvote his posts once and then in revenge, and there would be nothing he could do about it. I don't say you would, but commenting on downvotes has inherent risk that discourages people. And the more you seem to care about that downvote, the higher the chance you are one of them who revenge, so *asking* for explanation only makes it less likely you will get it.

Comment: @Wooble \`code ticks\` for the parts of error messages that are code are OK and I would encourage them (or edit them in). Code block for a whole error message can make a crazy rainbow out of regular sentence, and that's not good.

Comment: @Mołot: Hm. Okay. Good point. And no i'm not one of them. I try to improve the quality of SO, so also the quality of my own posts. So i'll learn in every question. But your though could be right. But it is a reason to downvote if someone disagrees with something? For this case, i added the `discussion`-tag. I will discuss about my question...

Comment: I'm not saying you are one of them. On the other hand, they say "I'm not like that" just as well as you do ;) No way to tell.

Comment: @Mołot: It's just a way of trust (is this correct in english? :/ ). On 702 votes, there are only 49 down votes. I don't know why i should do that. Why i should be happy when someone have less or more rep's than me? :)

Comment: Yea you are basically right but they are some donkeys here who think otherwise and spoils it for us all. Not your fault, but you'll have live with it like we all do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had a [similar feeling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197220/is-the-quality-of-question-titles-suffering-due-to-over-zealous-reject-point-hun) of my edits being disregarded as too minor, but through the feedback received here, I came to appreciate that if I feel strongly about an issue with a post that irks me, I should ensure that I correct as many possible flaws in the post as possible.

For constructive feedback, I would look at a [recent suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18066#./18066?&_suid=137968343732808258740838968869) of yours:

> I marked as answerd this question:
>
> How to develop a web application compatible with multiple database
>   management systems
>
> but the bounty was awarded by community to another user. Why?

At least the obvious spelling mistake should have also been corrected.

Neglecting to fix all obvious issues will give a negative impression on the people reviewing your edit.

Comment: OP has enough rep that his edits don't need review. (on SO, not MSO where your link goes)

Comment: `+1` Some good points thank you. You're right. But sometimes, I just see something that bothers me, and i correct it without reviewing the whole post. Okay it is maybe a bad practice, so thank you for your thoughts. I'll try it in the future. But you don't know any standard's?

Comment: Thanks @Wooble , I wasn't aware that we were given editorial immunity after 3,000(?). I've seen mentions on meta a few times about concerns with nobody "checking the checkers" for the reviews queue, this avenue  could also see a lot of less than desired edits being made. Using dTDesign as a convenient example, until late August (before 3,000 rep), they had 67 edit suggestions approved, and 39 rejected, which is not a great ratio to then be given carte blanche on post edits.

Comment: @dtDesign, FYI, the above comment is not to pick on you, rather just highlight a common issue with the system :) Regarding standards, yes, I think you're doing the right thing if you are asking specific questions about formatting on meta. If there is a particular point you have a question on, there is a high chance it has already been discussed here and needs digging to find the answers/recommendations. If not, let's keep asking and getting the answers to make the site even better!

Comment: @LeonStafford: Okay. No I get analized? I'll downvote all of your questions!!!! No, just kidding :P Anyway, thank you for your critiques. I think with this question, i learned more than with every other question i asked until today. Like i already said, I edited (also before reaching 3'000rep) very basic things, the most of theme were too minor, so they were rejected. But can I ask you, how you found this statistic?

Comment: sure, it's not able to be directly linked (that I know of), but if you go to a previous [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2771389) of yours, then click on the `(more)` link, it will show your **Editor Stats**

Comment: Oh. okay they're really horrible... So now the last one: THANKS A LOT. Really :)