# Title being rejected on StackOverflow

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

I'm trying to post a question/answer on StackOverflow and it won't accept any title I give it, saying "This title doesn't meet our quality standards". I've tried every possible wording that makes any sense and I can't post it.

A few titles I've tried:

- Enabling Dart button
- Enabling button in Dart
- Enabling a button in Dart
- Enable an element in Dart

...and 1,000 others I can't remember.

Comment: Can you really not think of a more descriptive title than that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/217863

Comment: Those seem like perfectly valid questions according to the "How do I write a good title?" page. In fact, that page recommends not starting with "How do I...", which is news to me. _edit:_ link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @RobertKarl You might want to consider raising that as a separate question or commenting on the question  (or answer) to ask for an update to current standards.

Comment: @anumuson Step 1) Can't find answer on internet, Step 2) Decide to post to SO to save others grief, Step 3) Spend 30 seconds writing question/answer w/ title like I would search for it, get non-detailed error about title, Step 4) Spend 3 minutes trying to tweak my title while still making it something I might search for, Step 5) Make account on meta and post there... One should not have to stop and get a degree in creative writing to share a little info on SO. Just an error w/ tips would've been nice for us casual users that just want to post a little something quickly and get back to work!

Comment: Also, I might argue that this is not a duplicate for 'How do I write a good title?'. I don't really care how to write a good title. I wanted to write that got past SO's validation logic. I already had the answer and was not interested in trying to get another. My point was to put something out there w/ the answer I was looking for so that Google would index it. If this is not what SO is for, let me know, but Google -> SO -> answer is how I get 80% of the answers I need on a day-to-day basis.

Answer (score 2):

None of those are questions. I'd suggest: "How do I enable an element in Dart?", or "How do I enable a Dart button?"

Comment: Some of the good examples from the page on writing a good title aren't questions, grammatically at least. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/143736

Comment: @RobertKarl That is correct.

Comment: As a casual user trying to share something, I was trying to make a title like I would Google it (I see logic there). If SO wants questions only (I see some logic there too), just say so in the error rather than sending one searching around for general guidlines, then apply each one to the attempted title to see which one is being broken.