# Correct spelling mistakes in titles

Tags: discussion, support, title, spelling

Should I take the effort to correct spelling mistakes in titles? I get a +2 from correcting, but this is a never-ending-task. Is this useful or should I spend my energy in something else?

Comment: And of course you should fix anything else that is wrong with the post at the same time.

Comment: @trobbins, of course - even more reason for fixing the rest of the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it make the titles easier to read and find? Do you fix unclear or uninformative titles while you're at it? **Do you find it personally rewarding?**

Answer (score 6):

The first part of a question seen is usually its title, and so I think good spelling within a succinct title, is important to give a professional appearance to our sites in search results.

When editing titles, I recommend that you adhere as much as possible to the advice in [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) - particular [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10651/215590).