# Please disable "tag in title" warnings for meta sites

Tags: feature-request, title, per-site-meta, warning

So I recently discovered that feature requests such as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103563/278659) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195741/278659) have already been partially implemented. Any title beginning with a phrase in `[square-brackets]` will trigger a popup warning:

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, as you can see, the above screenshot comes from a **per-site meta**, where questions about tags are frequent and so putting tag names in titles shouldn't be discouraged.

### Please disable this warning on meta sites.

I've never seen a meta question badly titled in that way; people with enough site experience to know about meta generally also have enough to know not to put tags in titles. The popup is at best useless, at worst actually *wrong* - after all, discussion of tags is *encouraged* on meta.